# HW impossibility?: "Create a rock paper scissors program in ruby WITHOUT using conditionals"

Tags: ruby

I'm in an introductory software development class, and my homework is to
create a rock paper scissors program that takes two arguments (rock,
paper), etc, and returns the arg that wins.

Now I would make quick work of this problem if I could use conditionals,
but the assignment says everything we need to know is in the first three
chapters of the ruby textbook, and these chapters DO NOT include
conditionals! Would it be possible to create this program without them?
Or is he just expecting us to be resourceful and use the conditionals?
It's a very easy assignment with conditionals though...I'm thinking that
I might be missing something here.

EDIT: I'm thinking of that chmod numerical system and think a solution may be possible through that additive system...

Comment: There's a justifiable movement called the [Anti-IF campaign](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/), which uses the objects to provide the condition itself.  There's some more information in [this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264192/1079354)

Comment: Any idea what falls into the _conditionals_ camp for you professor? Will `any?` or `all?` or `includes?` or similar methods count here? How about the `?:` ternary operator?

Comment: We have literally not used a single conditional operator. I'm familiar with Java and Javascript so I know all that stuff, but I want to do the assignment in the straightjacket, if you will. Houdini.

Comment: What did you learn in the first 3 chapters?

Comment: arrays, hashes, SYMBOLS, classes, objects, variables, lots of command line and emacs stuff, attributes, parameters (obviously), the == test, instance variables, basically everything up to conditionals

Comment: @boulder_ruby It frustrates me that professors have students write bad code like this from the beginning.

Comment: I didn't expect that when posting an answer to a three-year old question, and certainly not before the ink was dry.

Comment: Are you good at that game, boulder, paper, scissors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one only using hashes:

```
RULES = {
  :rock     => {:rock => :draw, :paper => :paper, :scissors => :rock},
  :paper    => {:rock => :paper, :paper => :draw, :scissors => :scissors},
  :scissors => {:rock => :rock, :paper => :scissors, :scissors => :draw}
}

def play(p1, p2)
  RULES[p1][p2]
end

puts play(:rock, :paper)        # :paper
puts play(:scissors, :rock)     # :rock
puts play(:scissors, :scissors) # :draw
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def winner(p1, p2)
  wins = {rock: :scissors, scissors: :paper, paper: :rock}
  {true => p1, false => p2}[wins[p1] == p2]
end
```

> winner(:rock, :rock) # => :rock d'oh! – tokland

Per @sarnold, leaving this as an exercise for the student :).

Comment: When answering homework questions, consider giving sketches of answers rather than fully functioning code... furthermore, that `==` probably counts as a conditional. :)

Comment: I don't see how a comparison is a conditional. It's frequently used in conditionals, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: == has been covered. I should've mentioned that

Comment: `winner(:rock, :rock) # => :rock` d'oh!

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt you've seen array/set intersections, so just for fun:

```
def who_wins(p1, p2)
  win_moves = {"rock" => "paper", "paper" => "scissors", "scissors" => "rock"}
  ([p1, p2] & win_moves.values_at(p1, p2)).first
end

who_wins("rock", "paper") # "paper"
who_wins("scissors", "rock") # "rock"
who_wins("scissors", "scissors") # nil
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple hash to the rescue:

```
def tell_me(a1, a2)
  input = [a1 , a2].sort.join('_').to_sym
  rules = { :paper_rock => "paper", :rock_scissor => "rock", :paper_scissor => "scissor"}
  rules[input]
end
```

Comment: When answering homework questions, consider giving _sketches_ of answers rather than fully functioning code...

Comment: @sarnold Any good teacher will fail him if his answer is this succinct. He better write it in his own words.

Comment: don't worry about it guys, I didn't have the guts to tell you but I re-read through chapter 3 and found out that it DOES have conditionals in it.

Comment: +1. @Anil, some comments: 1) Explicit returns are extremely unidiomatic. 2) maybe use "_" to join the strings? it would look better. 3) you can use an array-pair as keys, but the symbol is also ok 4) nice solution!

Comment: @tokland I had it in one line, but changed it for readability. Thanks for the compliment. Changed per suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I just think the simplest solution has to be something like:

```
@results = {
  'rock/paper' => 'paper',
  'rock/scissors' => 'rock',
  'paper/scissors' => 'scissors',
  'paper/rock' => 'paper',
  'scissors/paper' => 'scissors',
  'scissors/rock' => 'rock'
}

def winner p1, p2
  @results["#{p1}/#{p2}"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WINNAHS = [[:rock, :scissors], [:scissors, :paper], [:paper, :rock]]

def winner(p1, p2)
  (WINNAHS.include?([p1,p2]) && p1) || (WINNAHS.include?([p2,p1]) && p2) || :tie
end

winner(:rock, :paper)        #=> :paper 
winner(:scissors, :paper)    #=> :scissors 
winner(:scissors, :scissors) #=> :tie
```

Comment: this answer is a little bit more obfuscated than the other hash answer so I'm switching the correct answer to the @dereckrx's answer again. This is very cool though, kind of like a ternary operator in its brevity. Will be studying this one for some time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ruby, but I solved a problem like this long ago by using values for each one (eg, R = 1, P = 2, S=3).

Actually, I just googled after thinking about that and someone solved the problem in python [using an array](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110125200007AAx5P0z).

Answer (score 0):

pguardiario's solution above can be modified per the below to show both (1) which player won (as opposed to the choice of object that won) and (2) the result when there is a draw:

```
def rps(p1, p2)
   @results = {
   'rock/paper' => "Player 2 won!",
   'rock/scissors' => "Player 1 won!",
   'paper/scissors' => "Player 2 won!",
   'paper/rock' => "Player 1 won!",
   'scissors/paper' => "Player 1 won!",
   'scissors/rock' => "Player 2 won!",
   'rock/rock' => "Draw!",
   'scissors/scissors' => "Draw!",
   'paper/paper' => "Draw!"
   }

   @results["#{p1}/#{p2}"]
end

rps("rock", "rock")     => "Draw!"
rps("rock", "scissors") => "Player 1 won!"
rps("rock", "paper")    => "Player 2 won!"
```

...etc