# Using '&&' instead of 'if' for single instructions

Tags: php, semantics

I'd like to know if there are any problems with doing this:

```
($this->debug)
    && print "We're debugging right now";
```

instead of this:

```
if ($this->debug)
    print "We're debugging right now";
```

To me, it's just a style thing. Does it do exactly the same thing?

Comment: I think one of the most important code-metrics is readability. How well can a stranger take over your project?

Comment: Indeed, this I know. But does it make any difference?

Comment: It's the same of `if ($this->debug && print "We're debugging right now")`. They do the same thing, the only difference is that it takes me a moment to realize what it do.

Comment: I understand that completely - always have. All I'm asking for is any caveats... It's only for single instructions.

Comment: I don't think that downvoting him is fair. His question is a valid one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please don't. This is horribly unreadable. And it starts innocently enough, soon other "clever" developers would come and invent more "clever" ways of using this `&&` operator to avoid those "horrible" `if`s.

Please... Don't.

---

Functionally, yes, they will work the same.

Answer (score -3):

The shorter the code (up to a point!) the better.

You should **tell** your code what to do. You **should not** be asking your code, if you are allowed to tell it what to do. Your coding, like love, should be [Unconditional!](http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2013/11/unconditional-programming.html)

Need more arguments?

`&&` is better:

- fewer chars to type
- fewer lines of code
- lower [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)
- [if's are closer to *configuration* than logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE)

---

> **Conditionals** aren't always bad, but they can be (and **frequently are**) **abused**. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264192/2119863)

Some clever developers built-in similar solution directly into `PHP`, [@Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767002/2119863) the null coalescing operator `??` i.e. was introduced to PHP.

Functionally they will produce the same result. But one (`&&`) says you are a quality programmer, the other (`if`) says you are doing it as a side hussle.

Stop being scared of your code.

Be proud of your code.