# Not using IF, FOR, CASE (...) for making decisions

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm trying to write a procedure similar to the one below that would not use any of these expressions:

```
if | while | for | case | default | continue | goto | && | || | catch 
| ternary operator ?: | ??
```

The reason is that when a plugin like metrics (eclipse) calculates the cyclomatic complexity, each of those expression increases the cyclomatic complexity by one based on the number of paths.

```
String getWeekday (int order) {
        switch (order) {
                case 0: return "Monday";
                case 1: return "Tuesday";
                case 2: return "Wednesday";
                case 3: return "Thursday";
                case 4: return "Friday";
                case 5: return "Saturday";
                case 6: return "Sunday"
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
}
```

For this simple procedure the cyclomatic complexity would actually be quite high because of the amount of case statements, even though for the human brain it is not complex.

For practice, I'm curious if it is possible to create a procedure with as many decisions using mostly these or other expressions (while not excessively using the ones above -- one or two would be fine)?

```
else | do | switch | try | using | throw | finally | return 
| object creation | method call | field access
```

This would "fool" the plugin into thinking the CC is lower than it should be because there more paths but it ignores these expressions.

Comment: why would you want to fool a plugin by making what would mostly likely by highly unreadable code, if it even is possible

Comment: That code boils down to a `map.get(order)`.

Comment: how do you use `switch` without `case` or `default` and what is this `using` thing? Same for `else`, that's not a legal keyword without an if

Comment: Just because you are curious to fool a plugin doesn't reduce the cyclomatic-complexity of your code.

Comment: wouldn't most of this be optimized by the compiler anyway?

Comment: Sorry, some of these expressions are actually from C. But the ones that I am trying to avoid still hold.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is downvoted, because avoiding `if`s (and using polymorphism instead) is a natural OO way of thinking. See also the discussion in [If-less programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264145/if-less-programming-basically-without-conditionals).

Answer (score 2):

**First solution**

You could use `enum` for this:

```
public enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;

    public static String getWeekday(int order) {
        return values()[order].name();
    }
}
```

If you specificly need only the first letter to be upper case, you may change `getWeekday` method this way:

```
public static String getWeekday(int order) {
    String name = values()[order].name();
    return name.substring(0, 1) + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

or you may create constant `String` values like this:

```
public enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY("Monday"),
    TUESDAY("Tuesday"),
    WEDNESDAY("Wednesday"),
    THURSDAY("Thursday"),
    FRIDAY("Friday"),
    SATURDAY("Saturday"),
    SUNDAY("Sunday");

    private String name;

    WeekDay(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static String getWeekday(int order) {
        return values()[order].getName();
    }
}
```

**Second solution**

You may also define a `Map`, as Kayaman suggested in his comment, or Guava `BiMap` (depending of your needs).

Answer (score 2):

Without enums and if an IndexOutOfBoundsException (or NegativeIndex...) would be fine too without one of the given "bad" keywords.

```
public class Day {
    String[] days = { "Monday" , /*...*/ "Sunday" };

    public String getDay(int i){
         try{
             return days[i];
         } catch(Exception e) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
   }

   public static void main(String... args){
       System.out.println(new Day().getDay(2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of yours then for example the following will do

```
enum Foo {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesdey,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
     Saturday,
    Sunday
}

String getWeekday (int order) {
    return Foo.values()[order].name();
}
```

It's cyclomatic complexity will probably be identical.

Comment: The cyclomatic complexity of the above `getWeekday()` method is `1`, because there are no control flow statements, only an array lookup.