# Type Cannot refer to a non-final variable Asortiment inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: java, android

I add simple class to my application:

```
public class Nomenklatura implements Serializable
    {
        private Boolean SmenaIsOpen=false;
        public Nomenklatura()
        {
            SmenaIsOpen=false;
        }
        public String OpenSmena()
        {
            SmenaIsOpen=true;
            return "ok";
        }
        public String CloseSmena()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
        public Boolean GetSmenaIsOen()
        {
            return SmenaIsOpen;
        }
        public void SetSmenaIsOen(Boolean val)
        {
            SmenaIsOpen=val;
        }

    }
```

Application should work with one object this class.
When I use it in activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.presmena);  
        Nomenklatura Asortiment;
         Asortiment=(Nomenklatura) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Nomenklatura");
         Button but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
                    if(Asortiment.GetSmenaIsOen()) Asortiment.CloseSmena();
                    else Asortiment.OpenSmena();
                }
            });
    }
```

I get error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable Asortiment inside an inner class defined in a different method    Presmena.java.
Help to understand, what is wrong

Comment: Make it final: `final Nomenklature Asortiment = (Nomenklatura) ...`.

Comment: And please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lower-case letter. Methods as well. Also read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185321/when-should-null-values-of-boolean-be-used/11185400#11185400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it like this

```
final Nomenklatura Asortiment = ...
```

and it should work. When you declare inner classes and you make them use your local variables (which would normally be out of the inner scope, if you think about it), they need to be captured. In Java, you are required to mark such variables as `final`, to avoid unintended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your Asortiment variable as final

```
final Nomenklatura Asortiment;
```

Comment: You have to initialize `Asortiment` to some value here. Because it's final and you won't be able to initialize it later.

Comment: well, you have to initilalize it, but you haven't to do it right here.
You can write something like this 
final Object obj; 
obj = new Object(); 
and it will be valid