# database returning null to a Boolean variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

so i have this method:

```
class A(){

private Boolean Flag;

public java.lang.Boolean getFlag()
    {
        return this.Flag;
    }

public java.lang.Boolean setFlag(Boolean Flag)
    {
        this.Flag = Flag ;
    }
}

classB(){

boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()
form.setNavalFlag(navalFlag?"Y":"N";

}
```

database returns null and `Flag` is set to null.

What is a foolproof way where I can **100% avoid** NPEs? I know `Boolean` to `boolean` casting is not a guarantee as seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185321/when-should-null-values-of-boolean-be-used)

Update:
stepping through the code, the NPE is thrown in `fancyObj.getFlag()`...which doesn't make sense to me. i would expect the NPE thrown in `.setNavalFlag....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a foolproof way where I can 100% avoid NPEs?

One foolproof way is to explicitly check for `null` and to not attempt to unbox the `Boolean` unless you know it's not `null`.

To take your current code as an example:

```
boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()
```

This tries to unbox the Boolean. If it's `null`, you get an NPE.

The following modification will not have this problem:

```
Boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()
form.setNavalFlag((navalFlag != null && navalFlag) ? "Y" : "N");
```

Comment: what do you mean by `unbox` the Boolean?

Comment: @bouncingHippo: Convert it to a `boolean` (lowercase `b`).

Comment: read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()
form.setNavalFlag((navalflag != null && navalFlag) ? "Y" : "N");
```

**Edit of the Edit, as I had understood wrongly your comment :**

See my answer to the comment: `boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()` is automatically translated to `boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag().booleanValue()`

Comment: the NPE is thrown in `fancyObj.getFlag()`...which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: The problem is that `boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag()` really means `boolean navalFlag = fancyObj.getFlag().booleanValue()` (automatic conversion process named unboxing)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method

```
public java.lang.Boolean getFlag()
{
    return this.Flag;
}
```

to something like

```
public java.lang.Boolean getFlag()
{
    (Flag==null) ? Boolean.FALSE : Flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean primitive type, not wrapper in your value object.

If you retrieve the value from database yourself, you will have to be careful, you will have to understand how to interpret null, normally it is false.