# java Parse Boolean that may be null to Boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I noticed an issue with [java.lang.Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) class that it can not parse nulls. I know it has the [`parseBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean(java.lang.String)) static method but as it's signature states it only accepts `String` and not an `Object`.

In other words, it has the following signature:

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s)
```

but not:

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(Object)
```

What is the best way to check a Boolean value without falling on NullPointerException?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Convert a `Boolean` (that is either true, false, or null) into a `boolean`? If so, you'll have to decide whether you want nulls to be true or false.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185321/when-should-null-values-of-boolean-be-used) helps .

Comment: Do you think, `parseBoolean(null)` is only applicable for `parseBoolean(Object)`? If not, how do you want your Objects to be parsed to `Boolean`?

Comment: How did you fail on NullPointerException?

Comment: I receive from an object entity a field that mus be Boolean (because it is entity) and null is of course false. So i think the best answer is just to compare it to `Boolean.TRUE`

Answer (score 13):

Try that approach:

```
Boolean.TRUE.equals(yourObj);
```

Comment: OP might want the `null`. The question says into `Boolean` not `boolean`, still useful for others that just need the primitive

Answer (score 7):

If you want your parse to return `true`, `false` or `null` as a `Boolean` object, take a look at Apache Commons Lang. `BooleanUtils` has a one liner that does exactly this.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toBooleanObject(java.lang.String)

```
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(null) == null
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("true") == true
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("false") == false
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("YES") == true
BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject("nO") == false
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare it to `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`. Example:

`if (Boolean.TRUE == Box.modeled()) {
  //do somthing
}`

Comment: this is actually bad because technically you can create new Boolean objects : Boolean b = new Boolean(true);   b != Boolean.TRUE

Comment: so ... you answer your own question the very same moment you ask it?

Comment: also this does not answer your question