# HashMap throws unwanted Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, hashmap

From java docs of `Map`

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key.

But following code is throwing `Null Pointer exception`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        boolean bool = false;
        Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        boolean r = bool ? false : map.get("a");
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Comment: What did you not understand? Read again, *..or **null** if this map contains no mapping for the key.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895627/java-parse-boolean-that-may-be-null-to-boolean , his could be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is not with the hashmap, but rather the auto-unboxing of the result to a primitive boolean.

Use:

```
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    Boolean r = map.get("a");
```

Notice that `r` is a "big b" `Boolean` wrapper object, not a primitive `boolean`.

As `MadaManu` points out, be aware that `r` can be `null`, which can be quite surprising to readers of your code.  You might instead like to use:

```
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    boolean r = map.getOrDefault("a", false);
```

... if you wish to treat the missing key as the same as `false`.

Comment: I'd be careful recommending this as it could potentially throw an NPE later in the code and that's just pushing the problem away not explaining the root cause.

Comment: MadaManu: well OP is aware that the map returns `null` in the case of the unmapped key.

Comment: Some map implementations can store `null` values.

Answer (score 4):

The `get` is returning `null`, as the map is empty. The `NullPointerException` occurs on the attempt to convert ("unbox") null into a primitive boolean to give the ternary expression a primitive boolean type,  aligned  with the `false`.

The assignment is never even attempted, so that's not relevant.

Comment: It's actually boolean but that's ok.

Comment: Actually, the question was just edited

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

> If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException

In your case `map.get("a")` returns null and then Unboxing throws this exception .

You can use Boolean for workaround:

```
Boolean r = map.get("a");
// here r will be null.
```