# What is Polymorphism

Tags: terminology, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism)

My teacher said "Add Polymorphism to your code". What is Polymorphism?