# I need an example to implement the universal polymorphism(especially Inclusion)

Tags: java, polymorphism

In the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605669),I learned that the polymorphism has 4 types:

1. Coercion,
2. Overloading
3. Parametric Polymorphism
4. Inclusion

   So I did not completely understand what does mean by **Inclusion**, I need same example to implement this notion.

Comment: try going to google and searching "java Inclusion universal polymorphism example", there are examples online

Comment: i need link please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, search a little bit yourself to get a deeper idea of this topic... Here is one possible explanation:

> [...] subtyping allows a function to be written to take an object of a certain type T, but also work correctly, if passed an object that belongs to a type S that is a subtype of T (according to the Liskov substitution principle) [Wikipedia - Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping)

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    abstract void move();
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
    public void move() { ... }
}

class Ship extends Vehicle
{
    public void move() { ... }
}

public void moveVehicle(Vehicle v)
{
    v.move();
}
```

Here is an example for inclusion polymorphism:

```
Vehicle [] vs = new Vehicle [2];

vs[0] = new Car();
vs[1] = new Ship();

for(Vehicle v : vs)
{
    moveVehicle(v);
}
```

Or another example:

```
Car c = new Car();
Ship s = new Ship();

moveVehicle(c);
moveVehicle(s);
```

For additional information see the [Wikipedia - Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping) page... But still search yourself for this topic to get a deeper idea of it!

Comment: i use it lot off, without i know that is exactly,  the inclusion polymorphism notion, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion polymorphism means that you can instantiate an object from his super class.
For example you have

```
public class Person {
.
.
}

public class Employee extends Person{
.
.
}
```

So you can create an object

```
Person x = new Employee();
```

This is useful for example if you need to create a lot of different object that refere to a single superType

For example you have SuperTyper geometric_figure and SubTyper figure (circle, square, triangule,..). The geometric_figure may have two attributes x,y for the screen location and an abstract method "draw",to draw on screen, that each figure ,that extend it , need to implement

Thanks to `dynamic link` of java when you call **geometricFigure.draw()**, it will automatically know what type of geometric_figure you are calling (circle, square, triangule,..), and invoce this draw method

To manually check what is his specific class you can do:

```
Geometric Figure x = new Square();
if(x instance of Square){...}
```

A popular case is when you want to refere to a generic object like this

```
Object x = new AnyClass();
```

because the Object is the generic super class that every class have. (When you do not extend anythig, by default it extand Object)

Comment: thank you for your useful examples,  i understood well.

Comment: Happy to have been helpful!