# Polymorphism - Overloading/Overriding

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

I know that this question has been done to death at StackOverflow and that there are numerous questions posted on this already. **I've probably read every one of them and yet, there's this niggling doubt**: I think I understand Overloading pretty well, and Overriding. What gets me is Polymorphism.

For example, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism) explains this with `shape.Draw()`. I'm confused as to how this is different from Overriding (other times I'm confused with how it is different from Overloading).

Also - does Polymorphism inherently mean deriving from an abstract class? (I think almost all the answers I've read on the topic uses an abstract animal class and makes a cat and a dog meow/bark :)

**To sum up**, my questions are:

1. What is Polymorphism w.r.t. Overloading and Overriding?
2. Could somebody please explain Polymorphism without an abstract class - thanks!
3. Overloading/Overriding are not subtypes of Polymorphism, are they?

Edited to add a 3rd question and modify the 2nd question.

Comment: Overloading is orthogonal to subtype/interface (Java) polymorphism. Each overloaded method has a *distinct* signature. The compiler just saves the effort of choosing (possibly better) unique names :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. It's the ability to select more specialized methods in **runtime** depending on the object being used to call it.
2. Of course. Polymorphism could occur with no abstract classes involved.
3. No, overloading/overriding **are not** types of polymorphism.

Here's an example with polymorphism happening with no abstract classes involved.

```
// non abstract
class A
{
    public void a()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from A");
    }
}

class B
   extends A
{
    @Override
    public void a()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello from B");
    }
}

class C
{
    public static void SomeStatic(A a)
    {
         // HERE IS WHERE POLYMORPHISM OCCUR
         a.a();
    }
}
```

Polymorphism in class `C` occurs because `SomeStatic` method could be call with a **Reference to A object** or a **Reference to B object**. If it's called with a reference to **A**, `A`'s `a` method will be called. If it's called with a reference to **B**, `B`'s `a` method will be called. This ability of changing, on runtime, the actual method being called is called **Polymorphism**.

**Overloading** barely has anything to do with **Polymorphism**. In fact, you can hace **overloading** with no inheritance involved if you want. You could even have **overloading** with no **object orientation** involved. **Overloading** is just letting two function to exist with the same name but with different parameters.

**Overriding** on the other hand, is just re-defining a method on a specialized (inherited) class. **Overriding** a method is necessary for polymorphism to happen. Otherwise, the would be no **DUAL POSSIBILITIES** on runtime (take a close look at the example).

Class C is the key to understand it all:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C.SomeStatic(a); // will call A's a
        C.SomeStatic(b); // will call B's a
        // AND THIS IS POLYMORPHISM
        // C will decide WHICH METHOD TO CALL 
        // only at runtime
    }
}
```

**Poly**: comes from *greek*. Means **many**.
**Morph**: comes from *greek*. Means **form**.

So in **Polymorphism** there are **"many"** (*poly*) **"forms"** (*morph*) of calling a method. Which one will be called, depends on the object being used to call the method.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz - this is exactly what confuses me :) I'm assuming the equivalent code to `Class B : A` in Java is `Class B extends A`. Aren't you **overriding** the method `a()` of Class A in Class B?

Comment: OK, changed the syntax to **Java**. No, it's the other way around: I am overriding Class A's `a` method on Class B.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz - sorry fixed the typo, but my question is - how is this not an example of Overriding? Oh, I think I **may** have got it - is it because this is a difference in the **type** of the object rather than the method?

Comment: Yes, what determines which method will be called it's the actual type of the object. Not the method. You override the method, also means you **redefine** it.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but poly and morph are greek words not latin (the ph and y is a give away usually ;) )

Comment: @Voo: thanks! I always thought they were latin! My mistake. Will fix the post.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that from a different post too - fancy learning Greek while trying to learn Java/OOP ;)

Comment: overriding --> inclusion polym.

Comment: overloading --> ad-hoc polym.

Comment: I know it's an old answer. One thing though wouldn't A b = new B(); have been better instead of B b = new B(); to explain polymorphism? Reason being that the compiler would have called B's method after having controlled the instance type and ignoring the type of the reference variable?

Answer (score 1):

Actually polymorpishm is not something separate beside of overloading and overriding.

Both - overloading and overriding - are a specific type of polymorphism:

- Overloading is referred to as adhoc-polymorphism.
- Overriding is used in object orientation for type-polymorphism to implement different behaviour on subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is an OOP concept in which a single task is performed in many ways. Eg. You can pay bill through debit card , through netbanking.

It is of two type :

1) Compile time polymorphism : which  causes static binding(A signature matching technique that compiler use to match the signature). Operator overloading , function overloading is actually a way to implement compile time polymorphism.

2) Run time polymorphism : which causes dynamic binding. Overriding(redefining a method in subsequent sub classes) is a way of implementing the run time polymorphism.