# What does a type name in brackets mean?

Tags: java, syntax, casting

I was reading a program and saw the following syntax:

```
Pet pet1 = (Pet) objIn.readObject();
```

`Pet` is a abstract class, `objIn.readObjet()` means read the objects from the file,
but what does the syntax `(Pet)` mean?

Does it set the every object read from file as a new `Pet` object? But `Pet` is an abstract class, how can set a object in it?

Comment: To be precise: `(` and `)` are called parentheses. Brackets are `[` and `]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
objIn.readObject();
```

Returns a reference of type `Object`. You can not assign a reference of type `Object`, to a reference declared as type `Pet`. So you use this syntax to *cast* it. Casting is changing the type of something. In this case, the pointer to the existing `Object`.

**Example**

```
Object obj = objIn.readObject();

if(obj instanceof Pet) {
    // Make sure it is of type Pet
    Pet pet1 = (Pet)obj;
}
```

The `(Pet)` tells the compiler to now refer to this instance as a type of `Pet`.

**Edit**

I couldn't put it better myself, so Andrzej's comment can go here:

> Casting only tells the type-checker that you (the programmer) have more information about the real type of the object, than can be inferred from static typing. In this example for instance, readObject is only guaranteed to return an Object - but we can tell from the context that the returned value will actually, in reality, be an instance of Pet.

Comment: I would clarify that *casting doesn't actually change the type of any objects*.  You cannot use it to *convert* an instance of one class to another, e.g. to turn a `String` (such as `"4.2"`) into a `BigDecimal`.  Casting only tells the type-checker that you (the programmer) have more information about the real type of the object, than can be inferred from static typing.  In this example for instance, `readObject` is only guaranteed to return an `Object` - but we can tell from the context that the returned value will actually, in reality, be an instance of `Pet`.

Comment: I thought I'd covered that by saying it is changing the pointer to the existing `Object`. I agree though, this might come off a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type cast. [Read this](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

It means you can treat objects as (one of) their superclass(es). In Java, every class derrives from the class `Object` (except for the primitive types, that all have a corresponding reference type too, anyway). This means that I can cast `String`, `ArrayList`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` or just any other class you can think of to `Object`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but your final sentence is a little ambiguous. It almost reads like `String` could be cast to `ArrayList` etc.

Comment: Haha, oh yeah I see it too, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

> **But `Pet` is an abstract class, how can set a object in it?**

This relates to [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031385/474189). In object-oriented languages, such as Java, it is possible to make variable declarations like:

```
class Dog extends Pet {...}
Dog someDog = new Dog(...);

Pet pet = someDog; // <--- polymorphism in action
```

It doesn't actually matter if `Pet` is abstract or not. We are simply storing a reference to `someDog` in a variable "shaped" like a `Pet`.

We can call all the methods defined in `Pet` on our `pet` variable, but any additional methods defined in the `Dog` class won't be available.