# Is polymorphism strictly a type-theory?

Tags: interface, polymorphism, overriding, abstract-class, subtyping

I am learning OOP concepts, which do not really have well-established definitions.

I heard different things about polymorphism and can not decide what is right.

Most people will say that it is a type-theory. Meaning that a function is able to accept multiple types of parameters that have something in common.

Ad hoc polymorphism is about different overloads of the same function.

Parametric polymorphism is generic functions.

Subtyping polymorphism is that if a function accepts a certain class as parameter, it can also accept its subclasses. (Of course only those can be passed as parameter which are not abstract but concrete).

There is a seemingly different definition. There are those who say polymorphism means that a function can have different implementations (morphs/forms).
In that sense...
- interface functions,
- abstract classes’ abstract functions,
- and virtual functions that can be overridden by the subtype
...are all considered polymorphic.

As I was told, polymorphism in this sense can be defined as having different results if the same function is called on different objects.

And adding to the confusion, someone said only virtual functions are polymorphic because they already have an implementation.

For me the first way I presented polymorphism and the second seem completely different, but maybe they both fit the definition of polymorphism and it is just me being unable to understand it.

So what is polymorphism in programming? Is it just a type-theory?

In this question I would like to refer to this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163683/polymorphism-and-interfaces-clarification#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163683/polymorphism-and-interfaces-clarification#_=_)

It raises almost the same problem, but I could not really make out the conclusion.

Comment: To simplify the problem - I find that the easiest to way to define and understand Polymorphism is this: the ability to look at one thing from many different angles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

Yes, in classic inherited languages it works that way.

No, since in other languages the calling of a method on an object might be dynamically resolved.  (e.g. by runtime code searching in a list of objects as a field, so called aggregate in COM terms)

IOW that that method exists in the type of the object is not defined in type theory. At least not universal. The language might not even be typed.

For a statically inherited object model, it is however true. IOW Typing (subtyping/inheritance, de concept of virtual methods) is an implementation of polymorphism in languages with such object model. But not all languages do.

Some have dispatch polymorphism, and can add methods runtime (like objective C) or figure out of the method exists at all (e.g. COM IDispatch )

The classic test of polymorphism is the "the duck quacks".  Where you have a generic "animal" and call a method for "makesound", and if you assigned a duck it "quacks". So you call a method (pass a message in old OO jargon) on an generic object, and you get the behaviour of the more specialized object assigned to it.

What constitutes a "generic" object depends on the language. In statically inherited languages the generic object must have the method declared, sometimes with special modifiers (virtual) to signal overridability.

In other languages the generic object can be the root object, and the runtime will figure out if it has a makesound method.

Comment: Did you try to say subtyping polymorphism is the same as inheritance? Polymorphism and inheritance are usually separate OO concepts. The duck quacks test is what I wanted to mean. That which implementation of the makesound function is executed depends on which subtype (in this case the duck) it is called on. But there are those who say polymorphism is just that you can assign any subtype to the superclass. (Like Animal a = new Duck(); a = new Chicken();) Or does it mean both at thesame time? I am still confused.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that inheritance (and thus sub/super, virtual etc) is part of an implementation in a certain class of languages to achieve polymorphism. Polymorphism is just act on a object defined in a general way, but end up in the more specialized assigned to it (duck quacks). What the exact rules are is language dependent however, and not all languages do it via inheritance (or know the concept of inheritance)

Comment: So can we say that what is polymorphic about a generic method is that it can accept any type, and what is polymorphic about subtyping are the interface functions, abstract functions and overridden virtual functions? I mean when a function takes Animal as parameter and you pass a Duck, then the only attributes of the Animal parameter that are distinctive of the Duck are the functions.

Comment: Not necessarily any, just less specialized (animal) but has code (behaviour) of more specialized ones (duck).  If you really need to declare a method with "animal" or any object is subject to language rules.

Comment: I mean is it the fact that Animal has code of more specialized ones what will make it polymorphic? Or the fact that you can use any specialized classes with animal will make it polymorphic?

Comment: Just for illustration here I quote the answer of another question: “Polymorphism: The ability to treat objects of different types in a similar manner.” Animal is a generalized object with common attributes of its subtypes. And that is why you can deal with them in a similar manner because they all have Animal traits in common, and therefore the ability itself to assign a Duck to an Animal can be called polymorphism. But others go further and say: “Polymorphism refers to changing the behavior of a super class in the subclass.” That causes me confusion.

Comment: That last part is overriding. You replace animal.mysound with duck.mysound. That is polymorphism.  In statically-inherited languages you can only access features on an animal that are declared by animal, even if animal contains a duck. So if a duck has a "paddle" method, but that is not in animal, you can can't access it on your animal object.  But that is not really universal, but ok enough for languages that implement inheritance statically.

Comment: And that is an interesting thing. The person who stated "Polymorphism refers to changing the behavior of a super class in the subclass." also said that superclass should be taken in its loose meaning because the same thing can apply to interface functions as well, and did not restrict it to overriding. But there are those like you and others who simply restrict polymorphism to overriding. Can you tell me what do you think about this?

Comment: I don't restrict it, it was an example for classic languages. Counter example is objective C where you can add methods runtime to an object iirc.