# Benefit Of Object assigned to another object in java

Tags: java, object

im a beginner in java and i study everyday from books . there is a quistion that press my brain so hard for so long , what is usefulness of creating an object and give it an another object refrences ! i saw too many examples of this format .

```
Cat simon = new Cat();
Animal tiger = simon;
```

Comment: This is called polymorphism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used

Comment: Also, just for the record, it is customary to name object instances using lowercase / lowerCamelCase names, to avoid confusion with class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of an Object reference by itself is to tell Java to keep the Object around.  Otherwise, the memory used in that Object will *go away* (reclaimed by the Garbage Collector).  And, with the reference, you can trigger *actions* on the `Animal` (like `simon.eat()` and `simon.sleep()`).  Without the reference, you couldn't do this.  Anything you work on in any program must *stay around* by having some *reference* to it (like you did above).

The Object reference between `Animal` and `Cat` shows that "I can treat Cat, Dog, Elephant, Eagle, Moose, etc. any animal that is an `Animal` **like** an Animal."  (This is called **polymorphism**.)

So, an `Animal` can have actions like `eat()` and `sleep()` because all `Animal`s can `eat()` and `sleep()`.  But, an `Eagle` can also `fly()`.  So, `Eagle` has the `fly()` action defined.  And, you wouldn't put the `fly()` action in `Animal` because not all `Animal`s can `fly()`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful in cases in many different cases (although as a general term this refers to [`Polymorphism`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)), one I can think of is a `Parent` array creation. (`Parent` being the `Animal` class in this case, which is further extended by `Cat`).

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[] { simon, dog };
```

You can reference every item in the list simply by using `Animal` parent type, you don't have to worry about it being further of type `Dog` or `Cat` etc.

So suppose you iterate over this and call the `sound()/voice()` method for each element. If the method is defined in the `Parent` class (i.e. `Animal`), you can simple do:

```
for (Animal animal : animals) {
  System.out.println(animal.voice());
}
```

Comment: A piece of advice. You should not use generics to explain this particular question as that will raise questions about the lack of covariance for collections.