# Separate implementations of an interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am looking for a technique to have a single entry point for my interface, but where each implementation is handled differently.

Let's show an example.

I have got a couple of implementations of an `Instrument`-interface. Instruments ofcourse share some similarities (they make music, have something to do with notes and scales) but they are played very differently.

A `Musician` can play an instrument, and a gifted musician can play several instruments:

```
public interface Musician {
    void play(Instrument instrument);
}
public class GiftedMusician implements Musician {

    @Override
    public void play(Instrument instrument) {
        if (instrument instanceof Guitar) {
            play((Guitar) instrument);
        } else if (instrument instanceof Bass) {
            play((Bass) instrument);
        } else if (instrument instanceof Piano) {
            play((Piano) instrument);
        }
    }

    public void play(Guitar guitar) {
        guitar.strumWithPick();
    }
    public void play(Bass bass) {
        bass.pluckString();
    }
    public void play(Piano piano) {
        piano.pressKey();
    }
}
```

I have found a solution using `instanceof` but I am not sure if this is the way to go. I am looking for a design pattern or otherwise best practice to handle such a scenario.

Edit:
This example was of course very simple, let's make it a little less obvious. Because, as i said, there are many many kinds of instruments, which are played in different ways. Like a contrabass. How would I implement a `Musician` that plays regular- and contrabass?

```
public class Contrabass implements Instrument{
    public void play(boolean useBow) {
         if(useBow)
             playWithBow();
         else 
             pluckWithFingers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should declare the following method in `Instrument`:

```
public void play(Musician musician);
```

You can then implement it differently for each instrument.

For instance:

```
class Guitar implements Instrument {
    @Override
    public void play(Musician musician) {
        System.out.printf("Musician %s is playing the guitar!%n", musician.getName());
        strumWithPick();
    }
}
```

... and so on.

With this example, your `GiftedMusician` class would make less sense, unless you decide to use composition to associate an `Instrument` or many to a `Musician`.

In the latter case, your `GiftedMusician` would have a constructor overload taking, say, a `Collection<Instrument>`, whereas your `Musician` would only have a constructor with a single `Instrument`.

For instance (with `Instrument` as abstract class, to add core "functionality" to `play`):

```
class Musician {
    protected Collection<Instrument> instruments;
    Musician(Instrument instrument) {
        instruments = new HashSet<Instrument>();
        if (instrument != null)
            instruments.add(instrument);
    }
    public String getName() {
        // of course
        return "J. S. Bach";
    }
}

class GiftedMusician extends Musician {
    GiftedMusician(Instrument instrument) {
        super(instrument);
    }
    GiftedMusician(Collection<Instrument> instruments) {
        super(null);
        this.instruments = new HashSet<Instrument>(instruments); 
    }
}
abstract class Instrument {
    protected String name;
    public void play(Musician musician) {
        System.out.printf("Musician %s is playing %s%n", musician.getName(), name);
    }
}
```

**Edit** following up question edit.

If you need to parametrize a specific playing technique into your `play` method, without an overload anti-pattern and returning to the `instanceof` long list anti-pattern, you've got all the more reason to parametrize `play` with a `Musician`.

It's the `Musician` who decides the technique they want to play with after all.

Once within the `play` body, you can then adapt the playing logic to something in the lines of `musician.getCurrentTechnique()`.

Comment: This looks like it would work fine. But now, the `Instrument`-class has an import on `Musician`. So the instrument needs to know about what an musician can do. But an instrument could exist without there ever being any musicians (in the instrument factory), but a musician is nothing without an instrument.

Comment: `Instrument` doesn't need to now about musicians until it going to be played.

Comment: @Joost what Benten says. Plus the `Musician` parametrization in `play` is really optional. You could as well have a zero-arguments `play` method.

Comment: @Joost all the more reason to parametrize `play` with a `Musician`. The playing technique comes from the musician, right?

Comment: So then all musicians need to have a `#playWithBow()`-method? Even the pianists?

Comment: @Joost of course not. Read my edit. On a side-note you could also de-couple the playing technique from the musician, and have a static enum nested in an interface representing each family of instruments (e.g. strings would have *legato*, *staccato*, *pizzicato*. etc. etc.), then have the specific instruments implement that and validate upon the `PlayingTechnique` argument passed to their `play` method. All in all, broadening the question will get you more challenges than can be reasonably answered within a single SO question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You're right when questioning the use of `instanceof`. It *may* have some use-cases, but whenever you feel tempted to use `instanceof`, you should take a step back and check whether your design is really sound.

My suggestions are roughly in line with what [Mena said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024840/3182664). But from a conceptual view, I think that the direction of the dependency is a bit odd when you have to write a line like

```
instrument.play(musician);
```

instead of

```
musician.play(instrument);
```

A phrase like "an instrument can be played" IMHO suggests that the instruments are a parameter of a method, and *not* the object that the method is called on. They are "passive", in that sense. (One of your comments was also related to this, when you said that "*the Instrument-class has an import on Musician*", which doesn't seem right). But whether or not this is appropriate also depends on the real use-case. The example is very artificial and suggestive, and this may lead to suggestions for solutions that don't fit in the real world. The possible solutions for modeling this largely vary in the responsiblities, the question "*Who* knows *what*?", and how the modeled structures are intended to be used, and it's hard to give a general answer here.

---

However, considering that instruments can be played, it seems obvious that one could intruduce a simple method `bePlayed()` in the `Instrument` interface. This was already suggested in the other answers, leading to an implementation of the `Musician` interface that simply plays the instrument:

```
public class GiftedMusician implements Musician 
{
    @Override 
    public void play(Instrument instrument) 
    {
        instrument.bePlayed();
    }
}
```

One of the open issues is:

**Who (and how) decides whether a musician can play the instrument?**

One pragmatic solution would be to let the musician know the instrument classes that he can play:

```
public class GiftedMusician implements Musician 
{
    private final Set<Class<?>> instrumentClasses = 
        new LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();

    <T extends Instrument> void learn(Class<T> instrumentClass)
    {
        instrumentClasses.add(instrumentClass);
    }


    void drinkLotsOfBeer()
    {
        instrumentClasses.clear();
    }

    @Override 
    public void play(Instrument instrument) 
    {
        if (instrumentClasses.contains(instrument.getClass())
        {
            instrument.bePlayed();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I can't play the " + instrument.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

---

In your *EDIT*, you opened a new degree of freedom for the design space: You mentioned that the instruments can be played in different ways (like the contrabass, with bow or fingers). This suggests that it may be appropriate to introduce a `PlayingTechnique` class, as Mena also said in the comments.

The first shot could look like this

```
interface PlayingTechnique {
    void applyTo(Instrument instrument); 
}
```

But this raises two questions:

**1. Which methods does the `Instrument` interface offer?**

This  question could be phrased in more natural language: **What do Instruments have in common?**. Intuitively, one would say: Not much. They can be played, as already shown in the `bePlayed()` method mentioned above. But this does not cover the different *techniques*, and these techniques may be *highly* specific for the particular class. However, you already mentioned some methods that the *concrete* classes could have:

```
Guitar#strumWithPick()
Bass#pluckString()
Piano#pressKey();
Contrabass#playWithBow();
Contrabass#pluckWithFingers()
```

So regarding the `PlayingTechnique` class, one could consider adding some generics:

```
interface PlayingTechnique<T extends Instrument> 
{
    Class<?> getInstrumentClass();
    void applyTo(T instrument); 
}
```

and have different implementations of these:

```
class ContrabassBowPlayingTechnique 
    implements PlayingTechnique<Contrabass> {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getInstrumentClass()
    {
        return Contrabass.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTo(Contrabass instrument)
    {
        instrument.playWithBow();
    }
}

class ContrabassFingersPlayingTechnique 
    implements PlayingTechnique<Contrabass> {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getInstrumentClass()
    {
        return Contrabass.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTo(Contrabass instrument)
    {
        instrument.pluckWithFingers();
    }
}
```

(Side note: One could consider generalizing this even further. This would roughly mean that the `Instrument` interface would have several sub-interfaces, like `StringInstrument` and `KeyInstrument` and `WindInstrument`, each offering an appropriate set of more specific methods, like

```
StringInstrument#playWithBow()
StringInstrument#playWithFingers()
```

While technically possible, this would raise questions like whether a Guitar may be played with the bow, or a Violin may be played with the fingers - but this goes beyond what can seriously be considered based on the artificial example)

The `GiftedMusician` class could be adjusted accordingly:

```
public class GiftedMusician implements Musician 
{
    private final Set<PlayingTechnique<?>> playingTechniques = 
        new LinkedHashSet<PlayingTechnique<?>>();

    <T extends Instrument> void learn(PlayingTechnique<T> playingTechnique)
    {
        playingTechniques.add(playingTechnique);
    }


    void drinkLotsOfBeer()
    {
        playingTechniques.clear();
    }

    @Override 
    public void play(Instrument instrument) 
    {
        for (PlayingTechnique<?> playingTechnique : playingTechniques)
        {
            if (playingTechnique.getInstrumentClass() == instrument.getClass())
            {  
                // May need to cast here (but it's safe) 
                playingTechnique.applyTo(instrument);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("I can't play the " + instrument.getClass());
    }
}
```

Still, there is a second open question:

**2. Who decides (when and how) which `PlayingTechique` is applied?**

In the current form, a gifted musician could learn two playing techniques for the same instrument class:

```
giftedMusician.learn(new ContrabassBowPlayingTechnique());
giftedMusician.learn(new ContrabassFingersPlayingTechnique());

// Which technique will he apply?
giftedMusician.play(contrabass);
```

But whether the decision is made by the `Musician` (maybe based on some "proficiency" that is associated with each technique), or from the outside, will depend on the real-world problem that you are *actually* trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Add method

```
void play();
```

to the `Instrument` interface. Each implementation of it should be calling respective method, e.g.

```
public class Guitar implements Instrument {
  public void play() {
    strumWithPick();
  }
  private void strumWithPick() {
    // implementation details here
  }
}
```

Then `GiftedMusician#play(Instrument)` should be simplified:

```
public void play(Instrument instrument) {
  instrument.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the method `void play();` to your interface without any parameters. What you want to do is exhibit the behaviour of polymorphism.

So instead of using `instanceof` to check for each implementation, you have it in your interface as just `void play();`. Hence, whenever the interface is implemented, the `play()` method can be overriden and implemented specifically for the given class e.g. your `Bass` class.

It seems code examples have already been given in other answers but specifically look up the term `polymorphism` in the context of OOP. In particular this question has some good answers: [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used)