# Calling different functions in an easier way

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am fairly new to programming, and at the moment am creating a program with many different functions. At the moment, the user has to type in a command, such as 'time', or 'help', without the function brackets. I would like it to stay that way.

But my code for this is very inefficient:

```
x=input()
if x=='time':
    time()
elif x=='date':
    date()
```

At the moment it seems short, but I plan to have many functions. Is there a way to make a loop which does all of this?

Comment: There's basically the same question here where I explained how to use a dictionary for it: [Too many if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748617/too-many-if-statements)

Comment: I can't get it working with functions though :-(

Answer (score 2):

Keep all the functions in a list, and traverse through list using for loop.

In your example:

```
def time():
      print "this is time function"
def date():
      print "this is date function"
list1 = [date, time]
x = raw_input()
for foo in list1:
  if foo.__name__ == x:
       foo()
```

Output:

```
$ python new1.txt 
date
this is date function
$ python new1.txt 
time
this is time function
```

Comment: This wont work because the function object `foo` will never be equal to the string that the user inputs.

Comment: Assuming the input() returns string as per his example.

Comment: Yes and that string wont be equal to the function so the if statement will never be `True`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I will update this asap.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped :D

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer. Thanks :D