# Instance creation with virtual functions, why?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

i have a question about virtual functions or methods. I found a really nice post here on stackoverflow [link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443155) explaining why and how virtual functions work. I understand how virtual functions work now, but i still dont understand WHY u need them. If you look at the link and the provided example, he creates an instance like this:

```
A *a1 = new B;
a1->show();
```

But why would u ever want to create an instance like this if you want to use functions from B? Why not do it like this:

```
B b1 = new B;
b1->show();
```

why should i use the A pointer when i want to use a B reference?

I hope you guys understand what i dont get about this and can explain it to me.

Comment: You need to understand the whole idea behind polymorphism...the following link might help...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list although any book on basic oop should explain the concept.

Comment: I give a concrete example in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27099751/464581) to the question you link to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of **[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))**.

In short, polymorphism allows two different types (classes) to offer the same interface with different underlying implementations.

Rather than using A and B as an example, consider two classes **Motorcycle** and **Car**. Both **motorcycles** and **cars** can be **driven**, right? The way in which you drive those two vehicles is pretty different. Both classes should offer a **drive()** method, although their implementations are different.

```
class Vehicle {
    public:
        virtual void drive() = 0;
}

class Car : public Vehicle {
    public:
        void drive() {
            // Driving to work, however a car does that.
        };
}

class Motorcycle : public Vehicle {
    public:
        void drive() {
            // Driving to work, however a motorcycle does that.
        };
}
Vehicle *car = new Car;
Vehicle *motorcycle = new Motorcycle;

// We can both be driven, so we share the same interface.
car->drive();
motorcycle->drive();
```

This can be particularly useful when passing objects into functions. You have a function which implenments being taken to work. You really don't care **how** you get to work, as long as you are driven somehow.

```
void driveToWork(Vehicle *vehicle) {
    vehicle->drive();
}

driveToWork(new Car);

// It's Tuesday, your car broke down!
// As long as we use a Vehicle to get to work, all is well.
driveToWork(new Motorcycle);
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: In C++ object passed by value will be sliced. Syntax for call a method for an object is incorrect. If you mean pointers you should use them and you introduce memory leaks.

Comment: @Slava, I'm answering his question of why this is useful, not providing production ready code.

Comment: Nobody would expect you to provide production ready code, but introducing bad practice is questionable and `driveToWork(new Car);` is one, it either leads to memory leak or would require to call delete inside function.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the code base to also include a class `C` that's derived from `A`.

Now add a function `display_A`, which is defined as:

```
void display_A(A* aPtr)
{
   a->show();
}
```

You can use that function with an instance of `B` as well as an instance of `C`.

```
B* bPtr = new B;
C* cPtr = new C;

display_A(bPtr);
display_A(cPtr);
```

Here, a `B*` and a `C*` are automatically cast to `A*` before the call to `display_A`. `aPtr->show()` in `display_A` works regardless of whether `aPtr` points to a `B` or a `C`. That's the real motivation for creating `virtual` functions.

The purpose of using

```
A *a1 = new B;
a1->show();
```

is to demonstrate that `B::show()` gets called even when the pointer is of type `A*` if what the pointer points to is really a `B` object.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is that when you call a virtual function, it executes the *most derived form of that function* that it can.

```
class Message
{
     virtual void buildMessage();
}

class ShutdownMessage : public Message
{
     virtual void buildMessage() { /* Do a thing. */ }
}

class StartupMessage : public Message
{
     virtual void buildMessage() { /* Do a totally different thing. */ }
}

void prepareMessage(Message *M)
{
    M->buildMessage();
}
```

Now you can call this:

```
prepareMessage(myMsg);
```

on any message, and it will call the appropriate buildMessage function.