# c++ inheritance priorities of choosing functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I can't seem to understand how the compiler priorities to which function to go.
here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int f() {return 1;}
    virtual int g() {return 2;}
};
class B: public A {
public:
    int f() {return 3;}
    virtual int g() {return 4;}
};
class C: public A{
public:
    virtual int g() {return 5;}
};
int main () {
    A *pa;
    B b;
    C c;

    pa = &b;
    cout<< pa -> f()<<endl<<pa -> g() << endl; 
    pa = &c;
    cout<< pa -> f() << endl; cout<< pa -> g() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

to which function (g() and f()) will be called each time and why?

Comment: Run the program to find out and report back here if you cannot figure out *why* the code behaves as it does. But first, try to explain yourself, using your knowledge about virtual dispatch.

Comment: I ran it, the question was the why...

Comment: If you ran it, then surely you know which function was called, do you not? You did ask that.

Comment: you are actually are asking two questions which? and why?. If you already know the answer to the first, then better dont ask. I made a similar mistake recently and it really adds lots of unnecessary confusion. Always better to have one question per question even if they seem so closely related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sequence it will call `A::f()` and `B::g()`.

In the second sequence it will call `A::f()` and `C::g()`.

The reason for this is that `f()` as non-virtual method is resolved during compile time according to variable type (pointer to `A`). `g()` is marked as virtual method in `A` and therefore runtime resolve is done and it will always call the method of the real instance (`B` or `C`).

Answer (score 1):

`pa->f()` will always call `A::f()`, whatever you make `pa` points to because `pa` is a `A*` and `A::f` is not **virtual**.

`pa->g()` will call `A::g()`, `B::g()` or `C::g()` depending on what `pa` points to using [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used) because `A::g` is **virtual**:

- If `pa` points to a `B` (first sequence), it will call `B::g()`.
- If `pa` points to a `C` (second sequence), it will call `C::g()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a function is `virtual` you tell the compiler to use late binding instead of static binding.
So during compile time `A::f()` will be static bound so it is kind of fixed which method body to call.
On the other hand `A::g()` will not be bound to any method body during compile time.It will be decided at runtime which method body to be called (using vptr).

```
A *pa; //no matter what object you assign to pa, A::fa() will always be called
pa = &b;
pa->f();//calls A::f()

pa->g();// remember what function body to be called will be decided at runtime.
//will call B::f()

pa = &c;
pa->g(); //will call C::g()
```