# Initialize an object with a different class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, initialization

I saw this example:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#dynamic_cast

```
(...)
class Base { virtual void dummy() {} };
class Derived: public Base { int a; };
(...)
Base * pba = new Derived;
Base * pbb = new Base;
(...)
```

Why 'pba' is a Base object if it's being initialized with Derived? Why not make it a Derived object?

```
Derived * pba = new Derived; // use this instead
```

And is it just a C++ thing?

Comment: That's an instance of *polymorphism*. You cannot expect us to provide a fully elaborate answer as this is a pretty broad subject (and I'm sure there are some duplicates here).

Comment: And it's an example for dynamic_cast. If you write
_Derived * pba = new Derived;_
then this line has no sense
_pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);_

Comment: If you have both [cats and dogs in a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29%23Subtyping), and want to make all animals in this set make a sound then you call `Animal::talk()` for each animal, but this call will yield different results, based on the actual class of the animal.

Comment: `pba` is not a `Base` object, it's a *pointer* to a `Base` object. It is what it is in order to illustrate the subject of `dynamic_cast`. It seems like you have looked at the code without reading the surrounding text.

Comment: The other thing is that this is a simplified example.  A (slightly) more realistic version would be: `Base*pba = flag ? new Derived: new Derived2;` (where `Derived2` is a different derived class).

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes I did, but i'm not interested on the dynamic_cast, but in what situation declaring a object with a class and initializing with another would be used, and Dialecticus answered one. The link was just and example

Comment: @Downvoter the question is Why not make pbb a Derived object?

Comment: Because you're referencing an *example*, which demonstrates a feature of the language. Making `pbb` a `Derived` object would defeat the purpose of the example. If you want a real-life example for polymorphism, google it. It's an inherent feature of OOP and is explaines in virtually every OOP tutorial. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used) is a question on polymorphism with extensive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither `pba` nor `pbb` is an object but they are pointers of type base class `Base` so in your code you used he pointers polymorphically which means a base pointer can point to the same class or to its derived class object.

- the object is created with new not pbb or pba themselves, consider this example:

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;


  class Base
  {
      public:
          virtual void Print() const { cout << "Base print()" << endl;} // virtual function
          void Greet()const {cout << "in Base Say: hello!" << endl;}
  };

  class Derived : public Base
  {
      public:
          void Print() const { cout << "Derived print()" << endl;} // ovrode the base member pritn()
          void Greet()const {cout << "in Derived Say: hello!" << endl;}
  };

  int main()
  {

      Base* pba = new Derived;

      pba->Print(); // Derived print()
      pba->Greet(); // in Base Say: hello! ??? because Greet() is not virtual

      Base* pbb = new Base;

      pbb->Print(); // Base print()
      pbb->Greet(); // in Base Say: hello!

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  so at runtime the pointer pba and pbb can be assigned an object of Base or Derived classes thus the virtual member function are called accordingly.