# C# Inheritance misconception

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say that we have 2 classes. The first one is Person

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace People
    {
        class Person
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The second one is Teacher

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace People
{
    class Teacher:Person
    {
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I want to make a teacher object using this syntax `Person teacher = new Teacher();` When I make it and I try to refer to the Position property, I can't... Why does this happen? I can instead use this syntax `Person teacher = new Teacher() {Position="boss" };` but even though, after that I can't refer to the teacher position using "teacher.Position".

Comment: The variable is of type `Person`, which has no `Position` property.  Did you mean to add that property to `Person`?  Related to this, look into something called the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Meaningful type inheritance is more than just what keywords are used where.

Comment: Related: [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used)

Comment: Before asking this question you should read something about polymorphism, as @SamirAguiar proposed.

Comment: @Gh61 already did...

Comment: @peter basically this limitation is the compiler always ensuring that you never try to access memory that you should not be able to. As you can cross reference and assign variables from multiple assemblies that do not even need to be a concrete implementation like an interface, the compiler makes sure that what ever you declare as a variable can be safely accessed. As the `Person` class doesn't have a `Position` property, the compiler will not let you access it, even if the actual object acutally has that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the type of the reference. In the declaration

```
Person teacher = new Teacher() { Position="boss" };
```

the right-hand side creates a new object of type `Teacher` and also initializes the `Position` property. However, the reference `teacher` is of type `Person`. While the object referred to by `teacher` is actually of type `Teacher`, the reference itself is of the more general type `Person`.

Informally speaking, in the above declaration you state that you want to refer `teacher` to a `Person`, regardless of whether it is of the more derived type `Teacher`, so the reference itself does not 'know' that it refers to the more special type `Teacher` and therefor does not 'know' that there is a `Position` property.

More technically speaking, this is necessary because at runtime it would be possible to let `teacher` refer to other objects deriving from `Person`, say `Student` or `Wizard`, which would perhaps also would not have a `Position` property.

Answer (score 3):

You can reach it this way:

```
Person teacher = new Teacher() { Position="boss" };
var position = ((Teacher)teacher).Position;
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this:

```
Person teacher = new Teacher();
```

You create object of type `Teacher` but your reference type(`teacher`) is of type `Person` - it means that using this reference you can access only all members of type `Person`.

To access `Teacher` members you should either create reference of type `Teacher`:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
var position = teacher.Position;
```

or you should cast your reference to `Teacher` type:

```
Person teacher = new Teacher();
var position = ((Teacher)teacher).Position;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, the compiler simply does not know the inherited type after you assigned it to a variable explicitly declared as the base type.

The reason for that is, that while the object is still clearly an instance of `Teacher` the compiler can only be sure that this object is a `Person` at runtime, thus it will not allow you to access any properties of the `Teacher` class.

Declaring the variable as `var` will let the compiler determine the type of that variable based on what was assigned to it.

Comment: Declaring as `var` or as `Teacher`. If he wants to access `Teacher` properties.

Answer (score 0):

read about Abstract Factory design pattern :)
That will answer your question.