# How to make and populate common field in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Let say, I  have a **student, employee and car** class in a different structure in JSON file.

I already parse them and put the respective data to its POJO classes. The things is I wanna display data to inside a recycler view.
But here I have common field both three class is name and weight.

So, I wanna pass to list of generic to recycler view and populate them by calling like this:

```
tvName.setText(Object(should be generic).getName());
tvWeight.setText(Object(should be generic).getWeight());
```

It should display name and weight all the student, employee and car .

**RecyclerView** looks like

```
---------------------------------------------------------
CarName    
CarWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
EmplyoeeName    
EmplyoeeWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
StudentName    
StudentWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
EmplyoeeName    
EmplyoeeWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
CarName    
CarWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
CarName    
CarWeight
---------------------------------------------------------
StudentName    
StudentWeight
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you added all data into single arraylist?

Comment: what you passed to recycleview?

Comment: I try to pass only at a time either one of the class, how can I display without in objection just calling fields, it does not matter whether student or employee or car.

Comment: just make generic class with the fields name and weight and add all the data in that arraylist, does not matter whatever it is.

Comment: I have already class using jsontopojo and there are lots of other class. Let's assume with three class. but what happens if I have a more classes.

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve that, you need something called `polymorphism`, learn more from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used), [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). In order to respect that pattern I would implement the problem like this:

I would create an [`Interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) that has the methods you need:

```
public interface AttributesInterface {
    String getName();
    double getWeight();
}
```

Then I would make every POJO class implement that interface, looking in the end like this:

```
public class Car implements AttributesInterface {
    private String name;
    private double weight;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

In the adapter you store the list like this. If a class will implement the interface, then you will be able to add it in that array. So you will have an array that will contain `Student`, `Car`, `Employee` in the same time.

```
private List<AttributesInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then final step is in `onBindViewHolder` where you get an object from that array and set the corresponding values.

```
AttributesInterface object = list.get(position);
tvName.setText(object.getName());
tvWeight.setText(String.valueOf(object.getWeight()));
```

Also, you mentioned that you want a solution to work with multiple classes. As long as you implement the interface in each class that needs to be displayed, you can have a million classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one POJO class and you can add extra variable say *type*. So your POJO class will look like below.

```
public class MyClassModel {

    private String type=""; // S=Student, C=Car, E=Employee
    private String  name="", weight=""; 

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }   
}
```

Now you will get type in your RecyclerviewAdapter so you can write your logic according to type of data.

Comment: This would work only if all classes have the same fields. If a `Student` will have some grades and a `Employee` will have a salary, then you can't use it like this.