# Kotlin Inheritance question - inherenting class type cast

Tags: kotlin

Suppose i have the class:

```
open class Organism {
    open fun saySomething(){
        print("Nein")
    }
}
```

And the inheriting class:

```
class Person : Organism() {
    override fun saySomething() {
        println("Saying hello")
    }
}
```

Why when i run this code, i still get the person implementation:

```
 val x = Person()
 (x as Organism).saySomething()  // Output: Saying hello
```

This casting shouldn't run the Organism class implementation??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should not. It is because you are yourself telling the compiler that you are **overriding** `Organism` class method and the compiler should use this overridden method over the super(Parent class method) implementation. If you want to call **super** behavior of the parent, then in the overridden method in the child class, include `super.saySomething()` before or after the `println()` depending on your use. Also, if you write `val x: Organism = Person()`, this will compile because the Person makes `is-a` relationship with the Parent class and the compiler knows what to call in that case. This, in other words, called [Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used).