# Is there a way I can populate a List from another List without specifying each of the properties and using a select?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects like this:

```
public static List<CategorySource> categorySource;
public static List<CategorySource2> categorySource2;

public class CategorySource
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class CategorySource2
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way that I can populate the categorySource2 list from the categorySource list and ignore the SortOrder property without doing a Linq select and specifying each column.

Note these are just examples as the list I have that I need to populate has over 40 properties.

Comment: Does `CategorySource` has all `CategorySource2` fields? in that case you can use inheritance.

Comment: Is your objective only to avoid writing the mapping code? If that's the case I would give https://automapper.org a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using inheritance as proposed by @Guy:

```
static void Test()
{
  categorySource.Add(new CategorySource { Id = 1, Name = "Test 1" });
  categorySource.Add(new CategorySource { Id = 2, Name = "Test 2" });
  categorySource.Add(new CategorySource { Id = 3, Name = "Test 3" });
  categorySource.Add(new CategorySource { Id = 4, Name = "Test 4" });

  categorySource2.AddRange(categorySource);

  foreach ( var item in categorySource2 )
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id}: {item.Name}");
}

public static List<CategorySource> categorySource = new List<CategorySource>();
public static List<CategorySource2> categorySource2 = new List<CategorySource2>();

public class CategorySource2
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CategorySource : CategorySource2
{
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Since CategorySource is type of CategorySource2, you can add categorySource items in the categorySource2 list.

Doing this is called polymorphism.

[What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/58197730#58197730)

Doing this you can manipulate items while ignoring SortOrder.