# What's the meaning of interface as dependency of a class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, interface

```
interface SomeInterface {
        fun someFunction()
}

class SomeClass(private val someInterface: SomeInterface) {

}
```

What does it mean? As far as I know, interface can't instantiate objects and if it can then where should I implement `someFunction()`?

Comment: `someInterface` val needs to be of a class which implements `SomeInterface`. This means you need to implement the interface and use its object as a parameter

Comment: `someInterface` holds an instance of implementation of that interface. Just like if you allow `Any` to be a parameter, you can receive `String`, `Int`, ... everything. Because they are an implementation (actually extension because Any is class, but you can relate) of Any.

Comment: Related questions: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/) and [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/).

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that you cannot instantiate `SomeInterface` directly, but you can pass implementations of your interface to `SomeClass`. This way `SomeClass` can use `someFunction()` but doesn't care about the lower-level implementation details of the interface (aka polymorphism).

```
interface SomeInterface {
    fun someFunction()
}

class SomeClass(private val someInterface: SomeInterface) {
    fun doSomething() = someInterface.someFunction()
}

class SomeImplementation(): SomeInterface {
    override fun someFunction() {
        println("did something")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val someClass = SomeClass(SomeImplementation())
    someClass.doSomething()
}
```