# Correct hierarchy for shape classes

Tags: c#

I have a task where I need to do a well-projected hierarchy for classes of different geometric figures:

- circle
- circumference
- ring
- rectangle
- triangle
- etc.

At first, I made an abstract class `Figure` as follows:

```
abstract class Figure
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }

    public abstract double GetArea();
}
```

I planned that every other class that describes a particular figure will be an inheritor of the `Figure` one. And the idea of the `Area` in the `Figure` works right before the moment when I understand that `Circumference` has no `Area`.

**And I can't decide what to do next:** describe another abstract class `AbstractCircle`, delete this `Area` property and method from the `Figure` or just set `Area = 0` in the `Circumference`. Or maybe just make the `Circumference` to be an inheritor of the `Circle` and then set `Area = 0`?

Is it logically correct? I mean, would this logic be understandable for people who will read this program?

I will be glad to see the tips and comments.

Comment: This may help you : [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/58197730#58197730)

Comment: Since this sounds like homework, can you please post the exact text of the homework you've been asked to do?

Comment: Circumference is not a figure, it is a property of circle so you should not consider that as one of the classes. Every has differ properties which you can use to calculate area. So area is a common property you can create in base class and other needed properties in specific child classes.

Comment: Also: Each figure could/should have a property `Filled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are on the right track. Let's take a look at the different geometric figures that you are trying to classify:

- *circle* - (this is a shape)
- *circumference* - (this is a **property** of a shape)
- *ring* - (this is a shape)
- *rectangle* - (this is a shape)
- *triangle* - (this is a shape)

All of these are shapes except for the circumference. Like `area`, circumference is a property of a shape. Each two-dimensional shape can have a circumference, which will be implemented in a different way per shape. Thus, your `Figure` class should not need to be implemented by `circumference`. Rather, `circumference` should be a property of your `abstract class`:

```
abstract class Figure
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }    
    public abstract double GetArea();
    public abstract double Circumference { get; }
}
```

Now, all of your geometric shapes can implement this class without running into the difficulties that you were seeing.