# How to call the parent method that is overrided in a subclass from the method in the child class?

Tags: c#, oop, methods, method-call

I want to call FamilyCar method Move(). If FamilyCar is a LandVehicle, I want to call LandVehicle Move() method at the same time.
I'm looking for very basic way to do it.

Base class

```
class LandVehicle : Vehicle
    {
        public override string Move()
        {
            return "Move on the wheels";
        }
    }
```

Subclass

```
class FamilyCar : LandVehicle
{
        public override string Move()
        {
            return "Pip pip!";
        }
}
```

Comment: “If FamilyCar is a LandVehicle...” What do you mean? A FamilyCar is always a LandVehicle.

Comment: True, the fact is that I have more subclasses except FamilyCar. For each LandVehicle i want method Move() from LandVehicle to call and additionaly call their own method called the same that is more specified.

Comment: Did you mean "If LandVehicle is a FamilyCar..."? And what would the method return? Would it return what `LandVehicle.Move` returns or would it return what `FamilyCar.Move` returns? It can't return both.

Comment: do you mean how to call base method in derived class like `base.Move()` in `FamilyCar.Move()`?

Comment: You can use `base.Move()` to call the parent's `move` function. Of course you can't `return` twice so you have to refactor that part.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that what i was looking for. base.Move() Ty guys!

Comment: @h0ax That is part of polymorphism mechanisms, and here, calling the base class as you ask for: [What is polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/58197730#58197730). I hope this can help you to enjoy C# coding: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm).

Comment: Why this unclear, dup question has +2 ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use base.Move() to call the parent class Move method:

```
class LandVehicle : Vehicle
    {
        public override string Move()
        {
            return "Move on the wheels";
        }
    }
```

Subclass

```
class FamilyCar : LandVehicle
{
        public override string Move()
        {
            base.Move(); //this will call LandVehicle.Move()
            return "Pip pip!";
        }
}
```

Comment: Will call but does nothing with the result ...

Comment: @Selvin that's true but I think OP just wanted to know how to call the base class method