How to return the type of an item in a BindingList?
I have a Class called "Computer", and two classes that derive from it--"Hardware" and "Software". I have created a BindingList which stores items of both the Hardware and Software types, and am trying to figure out how to determine which type a given item is.
The code for my classes looks like the following:
abstract class Computer
{
  public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
  public int Release Year { get; set;}
}

class Hardware : Computer
{
  public string HardwareName {get; set; }
}

class Software : Computer
{
  public string SoftwareType {get; set;}
}

I then created a BindingList and added some stuff to it, for example:
public static BindingList<Computer> Components = new BindingList<Computer>();

Components.Add(new Hardware { Manufacturer = "Dell", ReleaseYear = 2024, HardwareName = "Mouse" });
Components.Add(new Software { Manufacturer = "Linux", ReleaseYear = 2021, SoftwareType = "OS" });

...and so on.
Basically, what I want to know is how to determine whether a given item in the list is a "Hardware" or "Software" type, and how to return that value, so I can use it as a condition in If statements, etc.

if (component is Hardware)  or you can use if (component.GetType() == typeof(Hardware))

Generally, you don't; there isn't much point in having polymorphism if you're then going to fill your code with "if x is as software then, else if x is a hardware then, else ..". Find a way to treat them both as the base type, or keep separate lists if it is important to know the differences. Some method of yours only works on Software items? Consider passing it a list of only software items (LINQ method "OfType" can help) etc. For better advice tell us more about the context and why you want to check the type eg if you're saving items, don't make your save method inspect the type, instead ...

... make a virtual method on the base type called "ToSavedRepresentation" (maybe it prepares a csv string) and then in each derived type override it with an implementation that creates a different string. Now you can just loop a list of the base type and call that method, but you get a different string shape depending on if it's a hardware or a software type. In other words you leveraged polymorphism by finding a way to treat an object just as if it were the base type but get a different behavior thanks to the different derived type implementations, without resorting to "if x is..."

Also wanted to point out that you can add a variable name after the type when doing "is", like if(x is Software s) s.SoftwareType = "Educational"

On the polymorphism note, see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used - even though its php it should be easily readable to a c# dev

That Software derives from Computer feels weird.
