What exactly is polymorphic - reference variable or object?
I am confused after having read different explanations of polymorphism in Java.

The Java Programming Language book:

polymorphism, meaning that an object of a given class can have multiple forms, either as
its own class or as any class it extends. The new class is a subclass or extended class of the class it extends; the class that is extended is its superclass.


Sun Educational Services Java course book:


Polymorphism is the ability to have many different forms; for example, the Manager class has access to methods from Employee class.
An object has only one form.
A reference variable can refer to objects of different forms.




What exactly is polymorphic - the reference variable or the object?

A reference is just that - a thing that refers to the object. It's like a phone number to get to the right object. It's a pointer. It doesn't do anything.

@AndyTurner, my question is not about what a reference is. I know what a reference is. My question is clear - what should be considered as polymorphic - object or reference? One book says, an object is polymorphic and the other book says, it is reference that is polymorphic, and not the object.

The reference is not polymorphic. What says the reference is polymorphic?

@matt, The second book says - "A reference variable can refer to objects of different forms." It means that a reference variable is polymorphic.

Polymorphism is that you can use different references to describe the same object. "Dog d = new Dog();", "Runnable a = d;", and "Object o = d;" one object can take different forms. You're defining those forms. "Runnable a = [[any runnable]]" the reference isn't changing.

Let's say Dog and Cat extend Animal. Animal a = new Dog();  a = new Cat();  - notice that the same reference variable is being used to refer to different objects. In this scenario, it is not the objects that are taking different forms. But it is the reference variable that is polymorphic. By the way, an object has only one form.

note that there are many interpretations or usage of the word object - it can be an instance, or the whole idea behind a class, ...

Your question is more about terminology than technology. You appear to already know what polymorphism is. The usage of the adjective "polymorphic" seems to vary with different authors, in the same way that natural languages such as English are not precise. There is no single correct answer to your question. By the way, if you're using a book by Sun Educational Services, that would be a very old book and you might end up learning about an out-of-date version of Java.

Polymorphism is one of the basic pillars of object-oriented programming and literally means “many forms”. When a method is polymorphic it means it takes on a different “form” (i.e. action) based on the specific type of the object. In the example in GhostCat's answer, the RegularWorker and Manager are both a sub-classes of the Employee object.   Let's say there is an abstract method in the Employee class named “calculatePay()” that is to be implemented in the sub-classes. The calculatePay method is going to behave differently for the Manager than it will the RegularWorker (this is polymorphism).

At any given time, a specific reference variable points to a distinct object.
At any given time, a specific object is just that: "that object".
Picking up some sort of class hierarchy, with a base class Employee and subclasses such as Manager or RegularWorker.
An object of class Manager is always that, the object itself can't ever be turned into an instance of RegularWorker for example.
But a reference variable for Employee can change:
Employee e = new Manager("John Doe");
if (whatevever) { 
  e = new RegularWorker("Jane Doe");

The moment polymorphism kicks in is when you invoke a method on e at runtime, because then the JVM decides which method should actually be invoked (based on the concrete specific type of the object that e is pointing to at that moment).

Polymorphism is closely related to inheritance (without inheritance there is no polymorphism), and is the change of behavior of a method, depending on what type of object invokes it, let's go with an example:
abstract class Animal {
  public abstract void move();
}

class Fish extends Animal {
   public void move() {
      System.out.println( "swim" );
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   public void move() {
      System.out.println( "run" );
   }
}

class Main {
   Animal ani[];

   public Main() {
      ani = new Animal[] { 
         new Dog(), new Fish()
      };
      ani[ 0 ].move();  // print "run"
      ani[ 1 ].move();  // print "swim"
   }
}

When we call ani[ x ].move(), we do not know the type of the object, however, thanks to polymorphism, the correct method is invoked.


In programming language theory and type theory, polymorphism is the use of a single symbol to represent multiple different types. -- Luca Cardelli et. al.


In object-oriented programming, polymorphism is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types. -- Bjarne Stroustrup

class Animal {
    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Animal generic noise");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Dog specific - Woof woof");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Cat specific - Meow");
    }
}
public class TestAnimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        a.makeNoise();
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.makeNoise();
        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.makeNoise();  
        a = d;
        a.makeNoise();
        a = c;
        a.makeNoise();      
    }
}

The reference variable Animal a is polymorphic because it can refer to a Cat instance and a Dog instance, not just an Animal object. This is one aspect of polymorphism. A reference variable can refer to an instance of its own type, and its subtypes. The ability of the reference variable Animal a to refer to an instance of its own type and also its subtypes is polymorphic.
a = d;
a.makeNoise();

In the above code block, the instruction was to a.makeNoise(), but a different form of the makeNoise() method has been invoked at runtime. At compile-time it was a call to Animal class's makeNoise(). But at runtime, it was a call to Dog class's makeNoise().
This is another aspect of polymorphism - virtual method invocation.
Thus, I have concluded that - the reference variable is polymorphic, and not the instance/object. Object/instance has only one form.

My question was to determine what is polymorphic in Java - the reference variable or the instance/object? I have found that the reference variable is polymorphic, not the object.

I have discussed two paragraphs explaining two aspects of polymorphism, wherein I have discussed clearly what is polymorphic - the reference variable. Also, I have quoted Bjarne and Luca in the beginning - both conclude the polymorphic nature of the super-type. Thus, it is the super-type reference variable that is polymorphic, not the objects of sub-types.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used -> So polymorphism is the ability (in programming) to present the same interface for differing underlying forms (data types). Animal is the interface for underlying forms - Dog and Cat.
