# Is function overloading achieved through run-time polymorphism in Java. Also is operator overloading supported by Java?

Tags: java, function, oop, computer-science

Generally function overloading is achieved through run-time polymorphism in languages,but is the case in Java opposite? Because Oracle document says unless function is declared static ,it is loaded at run-time. So if a function is not loaded at compile time, then how can overloading occur?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean overriding rather than overloading?

Comment: *Generally function overloading is achieved through run-time polymorphism in languages*. Which language achieves overloading at runtime?

Comment: I thought overloading is compile-time polymorphism and overriding is run-time polymorphism.

Comment: Then you should see Raman Shrivastava 's answer.

Comment: His answer says "overloading is compile time polymorphism" which is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of function Overloading, it is  static (compile-time) polymorphism because the compiler knows which method is to be called based on the number and type of parameters. For example:

```
public class FunctionOverloadingTest {
    public void display(String first) {
        System.out.println("I have one parameter");
    }

    public void display(String first, String second) {
        System.out.println("I have two parameters");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FunctionOverloadingTest functionOverloadingTest= new FunctionOverloadingTest();
        functionOverloadingTest.display("one");
    }
}
```

In this case, compiler decides which display method is to be called based on the **number of parameter passed in the function call.**

Answer (score -1):

No. Method overloading is compile time polymorphism.

In simple terms we can say that a class can have more than one methods with same name but with different number of arguments or different types of arguments or both.

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824763/is-polymorphism-another-term-for-overloading

Comment: Is it just me or is there something really wrong with the terminology of *compile-time polymorphism*

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783266/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-static-polymorphism-in-java), method overloading can be considered static (compile-time) polymorphism

Comment: My question is when function is not loaded at compile time , so how can its overloading occur?

Comment: What do you mean "when function is not loaded at compile time" all functions are loaded at compile time, thats how they are compiled

Comment: Can you post where in the Oracle Documentation it says that?

Comment: @AniDev I don't know about the answers but the [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) documentation on `polymorphism` only talks about *overriding* methods. There is no mention of overloading in the context of `polymorphism` in the documentation.

Comment: @ChetanKinger That's fair enough; I just mentioned that other question because it seemed to worth pointing out that two SO questions disagreed about whether overloading is polymorphism or not. It seems to be more of a general programming concept than anything specific to Java.

Comment: Yes  there is no mention of function overloading as polymorphism in documentation. The books say that and the previous answers on other links mention it to be compile time polymorphism. I read somewhere that unless a method is declared static,it gets memory in method area at run time, so my question was how come overloading is said to be a compile time polymorphism. While some answers also say it is not not even polymorphism.

Comment: @AmishaBansal There is no link between your previous comment and your question.