# Does base class object holds the drived class object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Below is the code and I want to understand few things:

```
public class Test {
    public void dosomething( ) {
      Derived2 d2 = new Derived2 () ;
      Base bobject = d2;
      string str = "str" ;
      bobject.Method1( str ); // I want to call Method1 of Derived1 class
    }
  }

  public class Derived2 : Derived1 {
    public void Method1( string s ) {

    }
  }

  public class Derived1 : Base {
    public override void Method1( double d ) {

    }

    public override void Method2( double d ) {

    }
  }

  public abstract class Base {
    public abstract void Method1( double d );
    public abstract void Method2( double d );
  }
```

I would like to know, what exactly happens when we assign derived class object to base abstract class object. I know instantiating abstract class is not possible. In my case, I am deriving class **Derived1**  and assigning object of **Derived2** class to base abstract class object. Now I want to access the **Dervied2** class method **Method1** which accept string argument. Somehow, I am unable to access this method. There are multiple classes exist which are derived from base abstract class. I want to keep things generic.

Comment: See the difference between overriding and hiding described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856449/overloading-overriding-and-hiding. Your overriding the double methods but the string method is hiding Method1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly happens when we assign derived class object to base abstract class object

There's no *object* assignment in you code, there's *variable* assignment.
After assignment, variable `bobject` refers to the same object, as `d2` does. Object type (and anything in the object state) remains unchanged.

> Now I want to access the Dervied2 class method Method1 which accept string argument

You can't do this in your sample without casting `bobject` to `Derived2`:

`((Derived2)bobject).Method1(str)`

> I want to keep things generic

Then, you shouldn't try to access members, which are not the part of base class.

Comment: as you mentioned "After assignment, variable bobject refers to the same object, as d2 does. Object type (and anything in the object state) remains unchanged". Then why can not I access Method1 of Derived2?

Comment: Because the type of *variable* (not the type of *object*, that variable refers!) is `Base`. Since `Base` doesn't contains desired method, you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

`bobject` is a type of `Base` which has two methods which accept a double, not a string (That method is defined in `Derived2`'s implementation).

To do what you requrie you'd need to cast `bobject` to Derived2, like:

```
var d3 = bobject as Derived2;
d3.Method1("String");
```

Comment: `bobject = new Derived1(); var d3 = bobject as Derived2; d3.Method1("String");` - happy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could even do

(bobject as Derived2).Method1(string);

This is because the resolution is based on the variable type.