# Perplexing output in Java with inheritance and overriding methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor, overriding

I stumbled upon this piece of code.
I tried to guess what will be the result of running it before actually doing so.
I was really confused when I saw them & in need of some explanations.
This is the code:

```
public class A {
    String bar = "A.bar";
    A() { foo(); }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A.foo(): bar = " + bar);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    String bar = "B.bar";
    B() { foo(); }
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B.foo(): bar = " + bar);
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println("a.bar = " + a.bar);
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
B.foo(): bar = null
B.foo(): bar = B.bar
a.bar = A.bar
B.foo(): bar = B.bar
```

Why is that?

- How is `bar = null`?
- Why is `a.bar = A.bar` even appear? I haven't instantiated `A` at all.
- And if `A` appears, why is it *after* `B`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few facts you ought to know before I start explaining every single step in your code's execution:

- Field references are resolved based on reference type and method calls are resolved during run-time (in a dynamic-fashion) based on the object type.
- `super()` is placed *implicitly* in **every** constructor even if you don't put it there yourself (it is not called if you call `super(int x, int y)` for instance).
- It is considered very bad practice to call "override-able" methods from a constructor - you will see why when we go through the execution.

Now let's break down your code step-by-step:

- You instantiate `B` by calling its default constructor `B()`.
- As I said before, the call to `super()` is added *implicitly* to any constructor, so `A()` is immediately called.
- Inside `A()` you call `foo()`, which is overridden in class `B` and that is why `foo()` is called from `B`.
- Inside `B`'s `foo()` you get the output `B.foo(): bar = null` since Java didn't get to initialize `B`'s fields yet (its constructor hasn't been executed yet!) and the fields of object type are initialized to `null` by default.
- Now that we are done with the constructor of `A()` we go back to the constructor of `B()`.
- Inside said constructor, we have the call to `foo()` again, which is again `B`'s `foo()`. But different from last time, `B` have its fields initialized (after the call to `super()`) properly so you get the expected `B.foo(): bar = B.bar`.
- Now we are back to the warm embrace of `main`.
- You access `a.bar`, and since as I said field references are resolved based on reference type, you get the field `bar` of `A`.
- Lastly, for the same reason, you call `a.foo()` which again triggers `B`'s `foo()` which prints `b.bar` once again.

And we are done! :)

Further references and worthwhile reading materials:
[Static and dynamic binding explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017258/static-vs-dynamic-binding-in-java)
[Order of constructor calls](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ309_009.htm)