# Error message while using inheritance in java

Tags: java

I am new to inheritance in java and I have the folowing problem. My base class is Plane, its child class is PlaneComponent and PlaneComponent's child class is PassengerCompartment. My program consists of 11 classes, when I ignore the PassengerCompartment class everythig's right. But when I run the whole program I get this message: `at Plane.<init>(Plane.java:14)
at PlaneComponent.<init>(PlaneComponent.java:1)
at PassengerCompartment.<init>(PassengerCompartment.java:11)`
which is printed repeatedly for so many times that I cannot see the top line of the error. The lines includes in error messages are the bold lines (here printed between ** **).

Plane:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Plane
{
int cap;
int pl;

public Plane()
{
    String desc = "Plane Description";
    String title = "Boeing 747";
    Random rand = new Random();
    cap = rand.nextInt(100) + 51;       //initialize cap with 50<value<100
    **PassengerCompartment a8 = new PassengerCompartment();**
    pl = cap / a8.cap2;                 // pl = sum of Passenger Compartments
    if (cap % a8.cap2 != 0)
    {
        pl = pl - (cap % a8.cap2) + 1;
    }
}
public boolean ready_check()
{
    CargoBay a6 = new CargoBay();
    a6.ready_check();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        EquipmentCompartment a7 = new EquipmentCompartment();
        a7.ready_check();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < pl; i++)
    {
        PassengerCompartment a8 = new PassengerCompartment();
        a8.ready_check();
    }
    System.out.println("Plane OK!");
    return true;
}
public void process(String e)
{
    if(e == "SecurityEmployee")
    {
        SecurityEmployee a14 = new SecurityEmployee();
        a14.workOn();
    }
    if(e == "MaintenanceEmployee")
    {
        MaintenanceEmployee a15 = new MaintenanceEmployee();
        a15.workOn();
    }
    if(e == "CleaningEmployee")
    {
        CleaningEmployee a16 = new CleaningEmployee();
        a16.workOn();
    }
}

public void values()
{
    System.out.println("Would you like more info about the plane's capacity? type Y or N");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inp = input.nextLine();
    while (!(inp.equals("Y")) && !(inp.equals("N")))
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, please type again");
        inp = input.nextLine();
    }
    if ( inp.equals("Y"))
    {
        PassengerCompartment a8 = new PassengerCompartment();
        System.out.println("Plane's capacity: " + cap);
        System.out.println("PassComp's capacity: " + a8.cap2);
        System.out.println("Number ofPassenger Compartments " + pl);
    }
}

}
```

PlaneComponent:

```
**public class PlaneComponent extends Plane**
{
public boolean ready_check()
{
    return true;
}

public void process(String desc)
{
    Employee.workOn(desc);
}
}
```

PassengerCompartment:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PassengerCompartment extends PlaneComponent
{
Random rand = new Random();
boolean inner = rand.nextBoolean();
int cap2;
String desc;

public PassengerCompartment()
**{**
    desc = "Passenger Compartment";
    cap2 = rand.nextInt(50) + 21;       //initialize cap with 20<value<50
}
public boolean ready_check()
{
    System.out.println(desc);
    if (super.ready_check() == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Passenger Compartment OK!");
        if (inner == true)
        {
            desc = "Inner Compartment";
            System.out.println(desc);
            if (super.ready_check() == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Inner Compartment OK!");
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public void process(String desc)
{
    super.process(desc);
}
}
```

Comment: This error message is printed so many times I cannot see the first lines of stacktrace. Can you help me find a way to see the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Also, when comparing Strings use the equals method
example e.equals("SecurityEmployee")

Comment: And no need for `== true`, just use `if(bool)`.

Comment: @IoannisStefanou Thank you

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou if an answer has solved your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your inheritance structure.

In `Plane`s constructor, you create an instance of `PassengerCompartment`.
`PassengerCompartment` extends `PlaneCompartment`. `PlaneCompartment` extends `Plane'. So, you are in a circle.

I don't think it makes sense for PlaneCompartment to extends Plane.
What you have is a 'has-a' relationship. So, `Plane` has a `PlaneCompartment` but neither extends each other.

Comment: I just removed "extends Plane" from PlaneComponent and everything works fine. Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular-inheritance-kind-of-situation (which <s>probably</s> creates a StackOverflow exception):

You instantiate `PassengerCompartment a8 = new PassengerCompartment();` in the constructor of `Plane`.

`PassengerCompartment` `extends` `PlaneComponent`, so the constructor of `PlaneComponent` is called *implicitly* (`super()`), which inherit from `Plane`. In `Plane`'s constructor you have the mentioned instantiation of `PassengerCompartment` and so on... So I would strongly advise to *not* instantiate classes that inherit from your class in the constructor of said class.

I would recommend reading <sub>my</sub> Q/A on this very topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814659/perplexing-output-in-java-with-inheritance-and-overriding-methods/34814660#34814660).