# Why the Output of this Java code is as it is?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, extends

I want to know why the following code:

```
public class Vertebrate {

   public Vertebrate() {
      System.out.print("Vertebrate ");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Mammal rabbit = new Mammal();
      System.out.println("Rabbit");
   }
}

class Mammal extends Vertebrate {
   public Mammal() {
      System.out.print("Mammal ");
   }
}
```

produces the output: `Vertebrate Mammal Rabbit`.

I was asked to explain in detail, but I don't understand why the output is like it is. Please someone help me out.

Comment: What do you think? Why is the output as it is? Did you try to follow the execution path of the program?

Comment: @AndreasFester I think it is because Mammal extends Vertebrate but I don't know ow to write a detailed explanation on that.

Answer (score 4):

You instantiate `Mammal` which *implicitly* calls `super()` before anything which invokes the default constructor of `Vertebrate`. This prints `Vertebrate` first. Then it continues with the constructor of `Mammal` which prints `Mammal` and then finally `Rabbit`.

For a more complex/advanced case of inheritance/constructors/overriding I have [written a Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814659/perplexing-output-in-java-with-inheritance-and-overriding-methods) a while back.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit call to default constructor of super-class :

```
class Mammal extends Vertebrate {
   public Mammal() {
      super();
      System.out.print("Mammal ");
   }
}
```

Comment: @pinquet62 That makes sense to me, thank you so much :).

Answer (score 0):

As you know the `main` method executes first. 
So these two lines are executed sequentially.

```
Mammal rabbit = new Mammal();
System.out.println("Rabbit");
```

So you can see why `rabbit` gets printed last.
Now for the first line ,

When you write `Mammal rabbit = new Mammal();` you are creating an instance of the Mammal Class right.
Now `new Mammal()` calls the `mammal` class's constructor. For any Java class the first line of the constructor is `this.super()` It does not matter whether you write it or not. Java does it for you.

So inside `Mammal` constructor the super class ie. `Vertebrate` gets instantiated first. This causes the Vertebrate to printed before mammal.

Comment: thank you so much Som :D

Answer (score 0):

As the **subclass constructor implicitly calls the super()**

/* calling super() must be the first statement in the sub class constructor in case of explicit call*/

for more info : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html