# Need an abstract function that can return different types of arrays

Tags: java, oop, types, overloading

I am working with a library with a method `JPanel makeBarGraph(Type[] dataX, Type[] dataY);` that has been overloaded. "Type" can be String, Integer, LocalDateTime... and many other types.

I currently have a data class, Post, that has several fields of several different types. I have made an enum that contains every field in this data class called "Content" and I made an abstract function called `getContent()` that each item in the enum implements like so:

```
AUTHOR {
    public String[] getContent(SocialMediaFramework f, Post[] p, String data) {

    }
},
LIKES {
    public Integer[] getContent(SocialMediaFramework f, Post[] p, String data) {

    }
};

    public abstract String[] getContent(SocialMediaFramework f, Post[] p);
    public abstract Integer[] getContent(SocialMediaFramework f, Post[] p);
```

The function is supposed to return an array of a specific type. This way, I can write the following function in my main class:

```
public void displayBarGraph(Content type1, Content type2) {
    frame.add(makeBarGraph(type1.getContent(), type2.getContent());
}
```

The problem is, you can't overload methods in Java by differentiating their return type, so my code won't compile. Is there another way of doing this so that I don't have to resort to a long list of if else or case statements?

Comment: Note that you may have to return an array for a school assignment, but List is generally preferred over arrays, and in this case a `Map<Post, ?>` would be more convenient for your caller, who wouldn't have to be so careful about keeping items sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Generic type

Stackoverflow Reference [How do I make the method return type generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic)

Answer (score 0):

## Which Overrloaded method is called is determined in compile time

#### By referring to [Static Vs. Dynamic Binding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017258/static-vs-dynamic-binding-in-java)

As overloaded methods are bonded using **static binding**, and static binding occur in **compile time**, even you have generic method `getContent` return different type for each enum, compiler can't tell which overloaded `makeBarGraph` you are calling in compile time.

### Suggestion

Suppose the outcome you are looking for is the `JPanel`, you can add an abstract method `JPanel getBarGraph` in the enum class. Then every instance in the enum can implement this method and call desired overloaded `makeBarGraph` method in the library.