# Overridden method called using a base reference that points to a derived object, what will be invoked at run-time?

Tags: java, object, methods, reference, overriding

**Question:** When an overridden method is called using a base reference that refers to a derived object, which version of the method is invoked at run-time?

I think it would be the method that was overridden, since its called by just a reference to the derived object; correct?

Comment: Be clear with your codes.

Comment: I think your question has to do with static/dynamic binding. Read the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647590/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding

Answer (score 1):

Yes, method of the derived object will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, derived object method will be called. Use the following example to experience.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        print(b);
    }

    public static void print(A a) {
        System.out.println(a.run());
    }
}

class A{
    public String run () {
       return "A";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public String run () {
        return "B";
    }
}
```