# Static/Dynamically Scoped,Typed,Binding

Tags: python, c++, scope

I am asking this just to clarify if i am thinking right.

Statically/Dynamically typed 
A language is statically typed if the type of a variable is known at compile time. This in practice means that you as the programmer must specify what type each variable is. Example: Java, C, C++.

A language is dynamically typed if the type of a variable is interpreted at runtime. This means that you as a programmer can write a little quicker because you do not have to specify type everytime. Example: Perl

Static/Dynamic Binding-which the following link clearly explains the difference
[Static Binding and Dynamic Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647590/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding)

The main thing that i want to ask starts from here.
I know the difference between Static Scoping and Dynamic Scoping.
However as i was going through stack overflow people said that C++ and Python are Statically Scoped.

In c++ if i type

```
int void main(){
   cout<<i;          
   int i=15;
}  
int i=10;
```

It works(even in java).However its python equivalent

```
def foo():
    print(x)
    x=10
x='global'
foo()
```

Gives an error.

Answer (score 4):

The scope is static in Python as well as in C++. The difference between those languages is related to rules that define start and end of the scope of names.

In C++ the variable `i` is considered as global before the local definition `int i=15;`.

In Python:
[What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body,
>   it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

[Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html):

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
>   enclosing scope.

So, since the variable `x` is assined inside `foo()` it is assumed to be a local variable starting from the beginning of the function `foo()`.
It is possible to treat `x` within entire function block as global using the `global` keyword:

```
def foo():                
    global x              # name 'x' refers to the global variable
    print(x)              # print global 'x'
    x=10                  # assign global variable

x='global'
foo() # print 'global'
foo() # print '10'
```

Actually it is possible to access the global variable `x` even if you want to have a local name `x` in the same function using `globals()` build-it function:

```
def foo():                # name 'x' refers to the local variable
    print(globals()['x']) # access the global name 'x'
    x=10                  # assign local variable
    print(x)              # print local 'x'

x='global'
foo()
```

Comment: So bascially the scoping rules are different