# Why is equals method on object class virtual?

Tags: c#, overriding

I was wondering why is `Object.Equals(Object obj)` virtual. I understand that we can override that method and write our own code for checking equality instead of the base `Object.Equals(Object obj)` method that checks only reference equality.

What I say is why override it when i can implement my own new method in my defined type? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: simple answer, everything in C# is derived from Object class.

Comment: The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declared in the base class and allow it to be overridden in the derived class. The override keyword is used to extend or modify a virtual/abstract method, property, indexer, or event of base class into derived class.

Comment: @viveknuna Simple but incorrect, not everything is derived from `Object`, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Why would you want to create your own method to do the same thing? You wouldn't want a `Maths` class with an `Add` method then a derived class uses `Add2` because it changes the functionality slightly. You would expect a single `Add` method.

Comment: Consider `Object o = new DerivedClassFromObject();` calling o.Equals with virtual/override will call `DerivedClassFromObject.Equals` without virtual, but new operator, it will call `Object.Equals`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838692/982149

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading and overriding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673721/overloading-and-overriding)

Comment: Why override? Because it's OOP.

Comment: I would say that it is mainly historical since generics were added in C# 2 so virtual Equals method was needed for non generics containers.

Answer (score 1):

You would override it for the same reason you would want to override any method rather than hiding it with a new method in a derived class: because of polymorphism.  You don't know how your derived class is going to be used by other code which only might know about the base class.

Clients may not even know that you've overridden the class at all, but they *do* know that they can call `Equals` on your instances because everything derives from `Object`.  If you have some other, new method, the code using your instances will not know to call that method instead.  It's the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) at work.

Answer (score 1):

> What I say is why override it when i can implement my own new method in my defined type?

Because that is how the language feature has been designed, as you know every type in C# is inheriting from `Object` and `Object` defines the methods with default implementation to check equality of two objects, and we as developers creating new types might want to modify the behavior how equals method compare two objects of specific type.

Here is an example to understand why it is virtual:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
Object o = i;
o.Equals(j);  // now what will happen here if you have'nt overriden it
```

the `int` type contains the overriden implementation of `Equals` method which checks the two integers for equality, so when we will call `Equals` method using reference of type `Object` it will call the implementation defined in the type `System.Int32`,and we had a new method defined in the `System.Int32` and not override the `Equals` method of `Object`, then we would see unexpected behavior as `Object` type implementation would have checked the memory addresses i.e reference equality.

Consider this example as well:

```
public class Person  
   {  

       private string _name;  

       public string Name   
       {   
           get   
           {   
               return _name;   
           }   
       }  

       public Person(string name)  
       {  
           _name = name;  
       }  

       public override string ToString()  
       {  
           return _name;  
       }  

   }
```

What if i want `Equals` method to not compare them by reference but instead we want to compare them on basis of `name`, in that case we would need to `override` the `Equals` method so that calling it either with `Object` type reference or `Person` type reference it would return the same result i.e not checking reference equality but checking the `Name` of two `Person` class objects.