# Child classes with the same interface as base class with the new key word

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to understand why it behaves as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AbstarctWithInterfcae
{  
public interface IBase
{
    void Display();
}

public abstract class Base : IBase
{        
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Display");
    }
}


public class child1 : Base, IBase
{
    public new void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("child1 Display");
    }
}

public class child2 : Base,IBase
{     
    public new void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("child2 Display");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase obj = new child1();
        obj.Display(); // writing child1 display
        IBase obj2 = new child2();
        obj.Display(); //Wrirting child1 dispaly
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

First Question :

In the above program as i am using new it should call base class method **why it is 
calling Child 1 Display**?

As per my understanding we have base class which already implemented the IBase so when we create instance for the child1 by referring to the interface it should call the base class method as it is inhering the base class and having the new key word.

If anybody gives explanation that would be appreciated

Comment: Don't you mean `obj2.Display()` in the second case (before ReadLine)?

Comment: Should the base definition of Display be Virtual, then the child implementations can override the base definition rather than hiding it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading and overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673721/overloading-and-overriding)

Comment: @vc74 yes. i did a mistake :). Now i got it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scenario 1 is because you are using `obj.Display()` instead of `obj2.Display()`

Scenario 2 is because you are using general interface reference `IBase`, (`IBase obj = new child2()`) and C# will select for the least complex type to fit this of the actual object type because it assumes you want to operate on the 'least specific version' of the type since you are not being specific.

Edit: Noting the downvote, I'm assuming someone doesn't think this answer is complete enough;

If OP would like to see the output correctly for Error 2, they can instantiate the type as `Child2 obj = new Child2();`

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is interface reimplementation.  In the first case, the base class is the most-derived class to implement the interface, so it will bind the interface's method to it's implementation of the method.  As that method isn't virtual, it can not be, and is not, overridden, so that is the method called when you use the interface on either the base or derived classes.

In the second example you re-implement the interface on the derived class (by adding it to the class's declaration).  This re-binds the interface's methods *using that type*.  Since it has a suitable method, its implementation is used whenever the interface is used to dispatch methods for the derived type.