# No suitable method to override in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method in my code, which takes a Guid as a parameter. I want to override this method with one that takes a string as a  parameter:

```
public class SendEmailApi: ISendEmailApi
{

     public async Task<EmailTemplate> GetTemplateByIdAsync(Guid templateId)
     {
         var response = await _emailClient.RequestAsync(EmailClient.Method.GET, urlPath: $"templates/{templateId}");

         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailTemplate>(await response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync());
     }
}
```

However when I try to implement, I get the error that there is no suitable method to override.

```
public async override Task<EmailTemplate> GetTemplateByIdAsync(string templateId)
{
     var response = await _emailClient.RequestAsync(EmailClient.Method.GET, urlPath: $"templates/{templateId}");

     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailTemplate>(await response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface ISendEmailApi
{
    Task<EmailTemplate> GetTemplateByIdAsync(Guid templateId);
}
```

I am relatively new to C# and .NET and any advice would be appreciated - I am sure I am missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: You don´t need to override the method. As you inherit from an interface just add a new method to the interface `Task<EmailTemplate> GetTemplateByIdAsync(string templateId);`

Comment: What you want is a new overload. [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) is used "to extend or modify the abstract or virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other method you want is not an `override`, `override` means you're overriding a `virtual` method in the base class. And you have no base class.

Remove the `override` keyword in your function and it will work as you want.

Comment: But as he is already using an interface he should add the method overload to it.

Comment: You generally don't change public interfaces to suit your needs, but you can do whatever you wish.

Comment: you are right. but he could simply change the type parameter to **object** so he wouldn´t need an overload at all :)

Comment: @MartinE - I hope you're being sarcastic. That sounds like an awful approach.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. In order to override an existing method it has to have the exact same signature as the method it is overriding. Since your method takes in a string it can't override a method that takes in a Guid. Instead I think you want to overload the method ([Overloading and overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673721/overloading-and-overriding#:~:text=Overloading%20is%20when%20you%20have,same%20name%20but%20different%20signatures.&text=Overriding%20is%20a%20principle%20that,method%20in%20a%20child%20class).)