# Calling a Method from "base.base" class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

"Assume the following code:

```
public class MultiplasHerancas
{
    static GrandFather grandFather = new GrandFather();
    static Father father = new Father();
    static Child child = new Child();

    public static void Test() 
    {
        grandFather.WhoAreYou();
        father.WhoAreYou();
        child.WhoAreYou();

        GrandFather anotherGrandFather = (GrandFather)child;
        anotherGrandFather.WhoAreYou(); // Writes "I am a child"
    }

}

public class GrandFather
{
    public virtual void WhoAreYou() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a GrandFather");
    }
}

public class Father: GrandFather
{
    public override void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Father");
    }
}

public class Child : Father 
{
    public override void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Child");

    }
}
```

I want to print "I Am a grandfather" from the "child" object.

How could i do the Child object execute a Method on a "base.base" class? I know i can do it executes the Base Method (it would Print " I Am a Father"), but i want to print "I Am a GrandFather"! if there is a way to do this, Is it recommended in OOP Design?

Note: I do not use / will use this method, I'm just wanting to intensify knowledge inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can only be possible using [Method Hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193848/method-hiding-in-c-sharp-with-a-valid-example-why-is-it-implemented-in-the-fram) -

```
public class GrandFather
{
    public virtual void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a GrandFather");
    }
}

public class Father : GrandFather
{
    public new void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Father");
    }
}

public class Child : Father
{
    public new void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a Child");            
    }
}
```

And call it like this -

```
Child child = new Child();
((GrandFather)child).WhoAreYou();
```

Using `new` keyword `hides the inherited member of base class in derived class`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the "new" keyword instead of "override" and remove the "virtual" keyword from methods;)

Answer (score 0):

This program gives error when u run.
Make sure the object of child will refer parent class then use reference type casting calling method
Ex: child child = new grandfather();/*here we are creating instance of child that refer parentclass.*/
((Grandfather)child).WhoAreYou();/* now we able to use reference type*/
Otherwise they show error under grandfather type casting .