# class casting in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, casting

Here is the c# code

```
class A {
   public int Foo(){ return 5;}
   public virtual int Bar(){return 5;}
}
class B : A{
   public new int Foo() { return 1;}     //shadow
   public override int Bar() {return 1;} //override
}
```

Output of

```
Console.WriteLine(((A)clB).Foo()); // output 5 <<<--
Console.WriteLine(((A)clB).Bar()); // output 1
```

How do we get this ouput.Can anyone explain the class casting process here.

***Update:***

And how does this show difference between shadowing and override

Comment: You override the `B` class `Foo` method with new, so it hides the `Foo` method of class `A`.

Comment: @Romoku: It doesn't *override* Foo at all. That's the point.

Comment: as a side note, you will observe the same behavior without using the new keyword.

Comment: @JonSkeet _Overloaded_ I'm sorry.

Comment: @Romoku: Not even overloaded. Just hidden.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess I just don't know the terminology.

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume that

```
var clB = new B();
```

The difference between the `Foo` and `Bar` methods is that while `Bar` uses inheritance and polymorphism to decide what implementation to call, the `Foo` method hides it's original implementation.

In, a word, `A.Foo()` and `B.Foo()` are completely unrelated, they just happen to have the same name. When the compiler sees that a variable of type `A` invokes `Foo` it goes in and executes `A.Foo()`, since the method is not virtual, so it cannot be overriden. Similarly, when it sees a variable of the type `B` invoking `Foo` it executes `B.Foo()`, regardless of the actual type of the instance that is contained in the variable.

On the other hand, the `Bar` method is defined as virtual, and the inheriting classes can (and are expected to) override it's implementation. So whenever a call is made to `Bar`, regardless if it is from a variable that is declared as `A` or `B`, the method that is actually called must be found as the "latest" implementation in the hierarchy of the calling object itself, with no impact from the type of variable that was used to refer to the object.

Comment: You: _the method is not virtual, so it cannot be inherited_ I think you mean "cannot be overridden". All methods are inherited by derived types (though some of them may not be accessible (like if they're `private`)).

Comment: To elaborate, when you do not specify `virtual`, then it is considered *static binding*, which means the called method implementation is determined at compile time.  When it is `virtual`, then it uses *dynamic binding* and the called method implementation is determined at run time based off the actual object instance.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, that's what I meant. The implementation is inherited, but the right to change it (override) is not.

Answer (score 0):

In the class `B`, you introduce a `new` method `Foo` with the same name and signature as the method already there (inherited from `A`). So `B` has two methods with the same name. That's not something you would do if you could avoid it.

Which of the two methods `Foo` that gets called, depends on the *compile-time* type of the variable or expression (of type `A` or `B`) used.

In contrast the method `Bar` is `virtual`. There is only one method `Bar` in `B`. No matter what the compile-time type of the expression is, it is always the "correct" override that gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
((A)clB).Foo()
```

is like saying "Treat `clB` as if it were an `A` (if you can) and give me the result of `Foo()`".  Since `A` has a non-virtual `Foo` method, it executes `A.Foo`.  Since `B`'s `Foo` method is a "`new`" method, it is not used in this instance.

Writing

```
((A)clB).Bar()
```

is similar - "Treat `clB` as if it were an `A` (if you can) and give me the result of `Bar()`".  Now `A` has a *virtual* `Bar` method, meaning it can be *overridden* in base classes.  Since the object is *really* a `B`, which has an `override` for `Foo()`, `B.Foo()` is called instead.

Comment: You can find an answer to your second question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673779/what-is-shadowing)

Answer (score 0):

```
var clB = new B();
//Uses B's Foo method
Console.WriteLine(clB.Foo());    // output 1
//Uses A's Foo method since new was use to overload method
Console.WriteLine(((A)clB).Foo()); // output 5
//Uses B's Bar Method
Console.WriteLine(clB.Bar());    // output 1
//Uses B's Bar Method since A's Bar method was virtual
Console.WriteLine(((A)clB).Bar()); // output 1
```