# 'using' block compiler generated code not visible in dotPeek or ILSpy

Tags: c#, ilspy, dotpeek

I am interested to look at the compiler generated code for the `using` code block which generates `try-finally`, but I do not see both `dotPeek` and `ILSpy` showing this detail. I used `ildasm.exe` to look at this code block and I see that it has the `try-finally` block in it but cannot understand it well...so wanted to see if these 2 tools would help.

Any ideas?

**UPDATED:**
So I recently used a struct which implemented IDisposable in my project and was worried if the `using` code block and struct with IDisposable would cause boxing...but I later found the following article which mentioned that the compiler optimizes for this situation and does not box when trying to call Dispose.

http://ericlippert.com/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box/

So I was curious to see what kind of code does the compiler generate for my using block.

A simple example repro:
[image]

Comment: Post some example decompiled code!

Comment: ILSpy (and I'm guessing dotPeek also) will recognize the compiler generated `using` statement expansion and reverse it back into a `using` statement.

Comment: If you're wondering about the IL, see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/introduction-to-msil-part-5-exception-handling). An MSIL instruction will be generated along the lines of `.try L_000b to L_001d finally handler L_001d to L_0027` along with an an instruction somewhere like `leave.s L_0027`.

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: Choose IL as the language in ILSpy and it will then show you the raw IL, so nothing is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free [JustDecompile tool from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) is able to show the details.

Basically (`Test` being a sample class implementing `IDisposable`), the compiled version of:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var test = new Test())
        {
            test.Foo();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

is decompiled to:

```
internal class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        try
        {
            test.Foo();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (test != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)test).Dispose();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why `test` is casted to `IDisposable`? One can just call `test.Dispose()` without casting.

Comment: @MatiasCicero see 'Remarks' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @MatiasCicero I assume the compiler do that, so the generated code is the same for both implicit and explicit implementations of `IDisposable`

Comment: @MatiasCicero It's cast in case it's implemented using explicit implementation.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: `Test` might [**shadow**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673779/87698) `Dispose`. In that case, `test.Dispose()` and `((IDisposable)test).Dispose()` would behave differently.