# Override a property with the same name but of different type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am wondering if there is a way to override a variable with the same name with a different type in the derived class. Something along the lines of this (although this code will not compile):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Point2D Point; // Represent a 2D point
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Point3D Point; // Represent a 3D point
}
```

The reason for doing this is that `A` and `B` may share similar properties, just that the dimension of the `Point` is different.

Comment: Just for reference: [What is Shadowing ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673779/what-is-shadowing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about `Generics`.

```
public class YourBaseClass<T>
    where T: class
{
    public T Point { get; set; }
}

public class A : YourBaseClass<Point2D>
{
}

public class B : YourBaseClass<Point3D>
{
}
```

So, when you are calling

```
var a = (new A()).Point;
var type = a.GetType();
```

the type of the point of the `A` instance is `Point2D` (or `null` in this example, since the reference typed property is not initialized yet.)

```
var point2D = (new A()).Point as Point2D;
```

*Note: the reason to use generics in this situation is to specify the return type of the `Point` property for the derived classes.

Using generics is much better solution than to use the `virtual` keyword in order to hide the base class's property and define a `new` one (aka perform shadowing). Now you have a base property which has a "settable" return type, instead of having multiple properties which hide each other.*

Answer (score 6):

You can't override it but you can use the `new` keyword to stimulate override (shadowing).

**Note:** if the reference to class B is of type A, you will get the A property and not the B property.
This means that you must be very careful when using the new keyword for shadowing base class properties.

[Here is a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399127/difference-between-new-and-override) about the differences between `new` and `override`

Using the `new` keyword instead of overriding properties can be very useful when the derived class property type is derived from the base class property type.

Comment: In general, shadowing members from base classes leads to a whole class of new problems, I would advice against doing this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree It should be used with extra caution, but can be very useful when used properly. I've added a clarification in my answer.