# C# generics type interference strange behaviour

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Consider the following code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        Print(a);
        Print(b);
        Console.WriteLine(b.Hello);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Print<T>(T t) where T : A
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(t.Hello);
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Hello { get { return "HelloA"; } }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new string Hello { get { return "HelloB"; } }
}
```

The output I got (.NET FW 4.5)

- //Print(a)
- A
- A
- HelloA
- //Print(b)
- B
- B
- **HelloA**
- //Explicit Writeline
- HelloB

Can anyone explain how I got the 2nd HelloA, as I was expecting HelloB ?

Comment: you need to override the hello function. not to add a new one.

Comment: Because in `Print()` method, when you printing `Hello` for class `B`, in that point he has 2 `Hello`'s, one local, one from base class and `Console.WriteLine()` method will print out the base one, cause it hides the inherited class property with same name.

Comment: The concept you have implemented is called as shadowing and you are expecting the result that can be achieved after overriding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public new string Hello { get { return "HelloB"; } }
```

The `new` keyword creates a *new* function which just happens to have the same name as the old one. Thus, `B` now has two methods: `Hello` (A), which is executed when invoked through a variable of compile-time type `A`, and `Hello` (B), which is executed when invoked through a variable of compile-time type `B` (or a subtype thereof).

Since your generic parameter is `T : A`, the compiler compiles `t.Hello` as a call to `Hello` (A).

`B` *[shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673779/87698)* (or *hides*) method `Hello` rather than overriding it.

What you probably wanted to write was:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string Hello { get { return "HelloA"; } }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string Hello { get { return "HelloB"; } }
}
```

Note that the base method is declared as `virtual`, and the subclass method as `override`.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. +1.

Comment: "Since your generic parameter is T : A, the compiler compiles t.Hello as a call to Hello (A).", why is that ? I would have assumed that the method address will be decided in runtime, since T : A, we can't know in advance that this method is A.Hello

Comment: @Benny: Generics are *not* run-time method binding. You can only access methods whose presence can be verified at compile-time: You *need* `T : A` to be able to call `t.Hello`. You *cannot* call `t.SomeMethodOnlyDefinedOnB`, which is (essentially) what `Hello` (B) is. The fact that C# allows you to reuse the name is just syntactic sugar. You can think of shadowing as some compiler magic which allows you to write `Hello` where you would actually need to write `SomeMethodWithAnotherNameThanHello`.