# Default Interface Methods in C# 8

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

Consider the following code example:

```
public interface IPlayer
{
  int Attack(int amount);
}

public interface IPowerPlayer: IPlayer
{
  int IPlayer.Attack(int amount)
  {
    return amount + 50;
  }
}

public interface ILimitedPlayer: IPlayer
{
  new int Attack(int amount)
  {
    return amount + 10;
  }
}

public class Player : IPowerPlayer, ILimitedPlayer
{
}
```

Using the code:

```
IPlayer player = new Player();
Console.WriteLine(player.Attack(5)); // Output 55, --> im not sure from this output. I can compile the code but not execute it!

IPowerPlayer powerPlayer = new Player();
Console.WriteLine(powerPlayer.Attack(5)); // Output 55

ILimitedPlayer limitedPlayer = new Player();
Console.WriteLine(limitedPlayer.Attack(5)); // Output 15
```

My problem is on the code:

```
Console.WriteLine(player.Attack(5)); // Output 55
```

The question is: The output should be **15** or **55**?!

According to the .NET Team:

[Decision: Made 2017-04-11: Runs I2.M, which is the unambiguously most specific override at runtime.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)

I'm not sure here beacuse of the keyword 'new' on the overridden interface?what should be the correct behaviour?

In case you need to compile it from source, you can download the source code from:
https://github.com/alugili/Default-Interface-Methods-CSharp-8

Comment: "I can compile the code but not execute it!" why cannot you execute it? IMO, output would be `55`

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the `IPowerPlayer` `Attack` method is explicitly implementing the `IPlayer` method, while the `ILimitedPlayer` `Attack` method is implicitly implementing it. Or maybe it's because it shadows it with the `new` keyword. It's probably a combination of both.

Comment: @BassamAlugili This is messed up.  I don't feel like it should compile allowing you to have two methods, same name, different functions, on each interface like that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto executing does not work I have build the branch and started the feature .everything working fine, compiling, intelli etc. except the  executing im getting an error --> Methods does not allowed in the interfaces

Comment: @BassamAlugili So isn't the answer that the output would be a runtime exception rather than 15 or 55?

Comment: Perhaps you should wait for a C#8 compiler?

Comment: @Michael Puckett II just check out the code and start it from the branch it will be compile without any problem!

Comment: I understand it compiles and I understand the new keyword being used but it's a mess.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto why? do you have a references for that? I believe 15

Comment: I would wait until Visual Studio preview gets support for c# 8 (currently it supports 7.3). You might have hit an unresolved bug

Comment: In java what we shall get? any java developer here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is because of the `new` keyword which actually hides the derived type implementation from parent type as it was exactly the same behavior before too for classes as well which we call [**Shadowing concept**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673779/what-is-shadowing).

So the output would be **55** as you have reference of type `IPlayer` for `Player` object and `ILimitedPlayer`'s `Attack` method is hidden from `IPlayer` because of the `new` keyword in it's signatures

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry about that, clarified more

Comment: I am not completely sure this is the correct answer though. Read the comment from the OP: "except the executing im getting an error --> Methods does not allowed in the interfaces"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto C# used to not support any visibility attributes like public private in interface, so i am not much familiar yet with C# 8 but if above code compiles of OP then looks like now we can define

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII You really didn't understand my comment. I am familiar with what's being done, and the OP posted the runtime exception, not me

Comment: this is exactly my first idea but if you thinking deeply, the most specific override at runtime is in the ILimitedPlayer because? correct?!

Comment: this might be of help too : https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288

Comment: @BassamAlugili Not really, because that's not an override, it's shadowing

Comment: yes, @CamiloTerevinto is right, instead of `override` it's `new` keyword

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto aha perfect! thank you! so why you think it should throw an exception and not hiding the "shadowing"

Comment: @BassamAlugili I don't think it should throw an exception, I was just mentioning the output you got when you ran that. It *might* be that the team hasn't tackled that feature yet, or it *could* be that there's no way to determine which method should run

Comment: I find it surprising that we're discussing a feature that hasn't even been decided on yet (the repo still calls having `new` an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)) and I'm not even sure this code compiles.

Comment: thank you all for help! @EhsanSajjad i will leave it as open for a while.

Comment: @DavidG That's what I meant by my last comment

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Indeed, but Ehsan is convinced the output is 55, I would like to know where that surety comes from.

Comment: @DavidG the comes from how shadowing works and we are not expecting any breaking change uptil now for how OOP works in general in the newer version

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you can get a "good guess" for how this should work without C#8 compiler. What we have here is basically:

```
public interface IPlayer {
    // method 1
    int Attack(int amount);
}

public interface IPowerPlayer : IPlayer {
    // no methods, only provides implementation
}

public interface ILimitedPlayer : IPlayer {
    // method 2, in question also provides implementation
    new int Attack(int amount);
}
```

So we have 2 interface methods (with same signature), and some interfaces (`IPowerPlayer` and `ILimitedPlayer`) provide implementations of those methods. We can just provide implementaitions in `Player` class itself to achieve similar functionality:

```
public class Player : IPowerPlayer, ILimitedPlayer {
    int IPlayer.Attack(int amount) {
        return amount + 50;
    }

    int ILimitedPlayer.Attack(int amount) {
        return amount + 10;
    }
}
```

Then running code from question outputs:

**55**

55

15

And I think it's relatively clear why.