# Confused with polymorphism written in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism

Hi my workmate just told me that it is possible to achieve polymorphism by hiding a base class method and implementing another method with the same signature in the derive class, Is this true and how could this be needed in real life situations?

Comment: The C# Programming Guide on MSDN has a [whole section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on polymorphism and it's uses, including Hiding Base Class Members with New Members among other topics.

Comment: I'm not sure whats unclear.  Its obvious that this question is about confusion on C#s hiding "feature" and actual polymorphism, and there's a question that addresses this confusion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your friend was talking about shadowing. It's not true polymorphism and should be avoided [Difference between shadowing and overriding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c)

Comment: Shadowing is just the VB word for what C# calls Hiding.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - thanks, didn't know that. Shadowing sounds much better.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much anti-polymorphism. The 'real' method for the object should be executed whenever called, regardless of the type of the variable, for polymorphism; you expect derived.Method() to be called whether you call it on a variable of type base or type derived, if the object in question is of type derived.

Hiding breaks that expectation.

Comment: +1 for the informative answer thanks :)