# What is the use case for this inheritance idiosyncrasy?

Tags: c#, inheritance, mono

When inheriting an inherited class, the new / override behaviour is not what I would expect:

```
$ cat Program.cs
using System;

class A {
    public virtual void SayHi() {
        Console.WriteLine("From A");
    }
}
class B : A { 
    public new virtual void SayHi()  {
        Console.WriteLine("From B");
    }
}
class C : B { 
    public override void SayHi() {
        Console.WriteLine("From C");
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        A p = new C();
        p.SayHi();
    }
}

$ ./Program.exe 
From A
```

As class C overrides the sayHi() method I would expect the output to be `From C`. Why does the B class's `new` modifier take precedence here? What is the use case for that? Especially as it breaks the obvious use case of having C really override A.

Note that the above code was run on Mono 2.10 running on a Debian-derived distro. But I have confirmed the same behaviour using the C# compiler in MS Visual Studio.

Comment: `new` from `B` is hiding the virtual overload in `C`. Change `p` to type `B` and you'll see the output from `C`

Comment: The question is "what is the use case for this?" but the actual question asked is "why does it do this?".  I'm curious what the use case for this is -- intentionally defeating inheritance in a way that's non-obvious to the consumers of your API seems incredibly dangerous.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`new` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) causes member hiding, which breaks the polymorphic relationship in your class hierarchy. The `SayHi` method of `B` is treated as *distinct* (not an override) from `A`’s (thus the choice of the word “new” as keyword). `C`’s method then overrides `B`’s, not `A`’s (which remains hidden).

Therefore, when you call `SayHi` on a `C` instance through an `A` reference, the runtime would resolve it against the `A` type, not the `C` type (within which `SayHi` is a “new” method inherited from `B`).

If, on the other hand, you were to run:

```
B p = new C();
p.SayHi();
```

…you would get the expected polymorphic result:

```
From C
```

**Edit**: Since you requested a use-case, here’s one. Before the introduction of generics in .NET Framework 2.0, member hiding was sometimes used as a means of altering the return types of inherited methods in derived classes (something you can't do when overriding) in order to return more specific types. For example:

```
class ObjectContainer
{
    private object item;

    public object Item 
    {
        get { return item; }
        set { item = value; }
    }
}

class StringContainer : ObjectContainer
{
    public new virtual string Item
    {
        get { return base.Item as string; }
        set { base.Item = value as string; }
    }
}

class QuotedStringContainer : StringContainer
{
    public override string Item
    {
        get { return "\"" + base.Item + "\""; }
    }
}
```

The `Item` property of the `ObjectContainer` class returns a plain `object`. However, in `StringContainer`, this inherited property is hidden to return a `string` instead. Thus:

```
ObjectContainer oc = new StringContainer();
object o  = oc.Item;   // Valid, since ObjectContainer.Item is resolved
string s1 = oc.Item;   // Not valid, since ObjectContainer.Item is still resolved
string s2 = ((StringContainer)oc).Item;   
                       // Valid, since StringContainer.Item is now resolved
```

The `QuotedStringContainer` class overrides the `Item` property of `StringContainer`, inheriting its `string` return type; however, it is *still* hidden from the `object`-returning `Item` property of `ObjectContainer`. If it were not this way, there would be no way of reconciling their disparate return types…

```
ObjectContainer oc = new QuotedStringContainer();
object o  = oc.Item;   // Valid, since ObjectContainer.Item is resolved
string s1 = oc.Item;   // Not valid, since ObjectContainer.Item is still resolved
string s2 = ((StringContainer)oc).Item;   
                       // Valid, since QuotedStringContainer.Item is now resolved
                       // (polymorphism!)
string s3 = ((QuotedStringContainer)oc).Item;   
                       // Valid, since QuotedStringContainer.Item is now resolved
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand how changing B would run the C's method, but is there a use case for breaking the polymorphic relationship between A and C? The guy programming C might have good reason to override A's method, but I fail to see the use case for preventing that, no matter if B is defined as `new` or `override`.

Comment: Since `C` derives from `B` which derives from `A`, there is no direct polymorphic relationship between `C` and `A`, but only an indirect one via `B`. If the `B`–`A` chain is broken, then `C` has no further claim to `A`, since `B` broke channel

Comment: I see, that does make sense. Thank you Douglas.

Comment: @dotancohen: I’ve added a use-class; check whether you agree with it.

Answer (score 7):

`C` is overriding the [shadowed](http://www.java-forums.org/java-blogs/3934-method-shadowing-inheritance.html) version of the method (which is being [shadowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) in `B`) and not overriding the one in `A`.

As result, when you are using a variable of type `A`, the `SayHi` defined in `A` is called, as *it* isn't overridden in `C`.

Answer (score 6):

`C` overrides `B`'s method, so when you cast it to `A`, you end up calling the virtual defined in `A`.

See [ECMA 334: C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) under 17.5.3 is pretty much your example (page 294).

Comment: Thank you for the link and the mention of page. I still don't see a use case for this behaviour, though, whereas the use case of overriding A from C regardless of B is quite obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Because the C class is not overriding the SayHi method in the A class, it's overriding the 'new' method in B. Since your cast is to A, the compiler resolves that as being a call to A.SayHi() rather than C.SayHi()

Answer (score 2):

The last [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645768%28v=vs.71%29) from this msdn page explains closely to what is happening here.

Basically the new modifier causes the method in A to be hidden from C, and since it is public when C overrides it overrides the method from B(which is treated as its own distinct method).

If you set the method in B to private, C would again override the method in A.

```
class B : A
{
    private new void SayHi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From B");
    }
}
```

Results in: `From C`

Comment: Thank you, but that example refers to private methods.

Comment: @dotancohen Yes, because making the method in `B` private exposes the underlying `A` method to `C` to be overridden, giving the expected result. Since you have a public `B` method, it is the one being overridden.