# Converting non-generic parent class to generic child

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

Have a generic class that inherits from a non-generic class like the structure below:

```
public class Result
{
     public string ErrorCode { get; set;}
     public string ErrorMessage { get; set;}
     public boo Success { get; set;}
     //Lots more properties

     public ClientResult ToClientResult()
     {
         //some pretty involved calculations of error coded and status
     }
 }

 public class Result<T> : Result
 {
     public T details {get; set;}

     public ClientResult<T> ToClientResult<T>()
     {
        //Need to call the parent class implementation and convert result to  generic ver  
     }
 }
```

My question is how can i call the parent `ToClientResult()` and convert the result to the generic version of `ClientResult<T>` and then i need to set a property of the `ClientResult<T>` to the details property of the `Result<T>` class.

I am sure i am missing an easy solution here, i really dont want to duplicate the parent class logic as it is pretty complicated.

Comment: and what is the relation between `ClientResult` and `ClientResult<T>`, and are you allowed to change them as well?

Comment: The result is simiar to that of Result and Result<T> and unfortunately i can't change them

Comment: If ClientResult<T> derives from ClientResult, my solution will work. Otherwise you'll have to go with one of the other two mapping-based solutions, which will be more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast an object of the parent type to a child type if it's created as the parent type (using `new ClientResult()`). It just doesn't work that way.

What you could do is factor the complicated code out to another method which you use to do the heavy lifting in both the `Result` class and the `Result<T>` class:

```
public class Result
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set;}
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set;}
    public boo Success { get; set;}
    //Lots more properties

     public ClientResult ToClientResult()
     {
         var clientResult = new ClientResult();
         SetupClientResult(clientResult);
         return clientResult;
     }

     protected void SetupClientResult(ClientResult clientResult) 
     {    
         //some pretty involved calculations of error coded and status           
     }

}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
     public T details {get; set;}

     // This now shadows the original ToClientResult method. The trap here is that if
     // you are treating your Result<T> instance as a Result, this method will not be 
     // called, and the return type will be ClientResult and not ClientResult<T>.
     // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c?lq=1
     public ClientResult<T> ToClientResult()
     {
         var clientResult = new ClientResult<T>();
         SetupClientResult(clientResult);

         clientResult.SomeProperty = details;

         return clientResult;
     }
}
```

This is all assuming `ClientResult<T>` derives from `ClientResult`, which is a little hard to tell from your question.

Comment: if the object isn't created using `new ClientResult()` it won't be of that type. The variable might be declared as that type and assigned an object of a derived type but that's different so your first statement makes little sense. You can't cast an `object` to a different type. You can only convert it. Casting doesn't change the type of the `object` only the type of the expression at compile time (objects don't exist compile time but only run time)

Comment: If ClientResult<T> derives from ClientResult,  an object of type ClientResult<T> is a ClientResult. It just doesn't work the other way round: an object created as a ClientResult can never be a derived type. Reread what I said.

Comment: I'm sure you meant the right thing and simply wrote something that confuses object type (runtime) and expression type (compile time). Objects exist at runtime only and in C# (in contrast to E.g. Ruby) you can't change the type of an object. You can tell the compiler that a given expression though declared as type `base` is actually going to return an object of type `derived` which is called casting (down-casting in this particular example) the object type is _not_ changed by a cast

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. It doesn't matter that the underlying type is still the derived type. I realise that my solution involves upcasting when passing the object to the protected method, but that's kind of the point.

Comment: I think you're also missing the point of the question. You're answering the exact wording (i.e. "how do I convert parent object to child object") without thinking about the intent (i.e. "I want to return a derived type from my derived class while reusing the work I did in the base class").

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this for me. Exactly what i was looking for. Seems very simple now thought.

Comment: You will need to pay attention to my comments on shadowing and be careful about how you're calling `ToClientResult()`.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy as I stated it's a comment to the wording in the first sentence it had nothing to do with the intend of the answer. Which is why I didn't comment on anything than the pleonasm in the first sentence but it seems pointless to continue that discussion

Answer (score 0):

in the `ClientResult<T>` class you could make a custom conversion from ClientResult to `ClientResult<T>`

```
public static explicit operator ClientReault<T>(ClientResult result)
{
       //do your conversion from one to the other here
}
```

you could then write ToClientResult like this

```
 //Generic argument remove from method declaration
 //because it was shadowing the type argument
 public ClientResult<T> ToClientResult()
 {
    var clientResult = ((Result)this).ToClientResult()
    var genericResult = (ClientResult<T>)clientResult;
    //do what you need to do with the generically typed object
    //...
    return genericResult
 }
```

That said this situations often arises when there's a flaw in the inheritance chain. E.g. when there's no is-a relationship between the base and derived class

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly do the conversion:

```
    public class ClientResult
    {
        public int a {get;set;}
    }

    public class ClientResult<T> : ClientResult
    {
        public ClientResult(ClientResult cr)
        {
            this.a = cr.a;
        }
    }

    public class Result<T> : Result
    {
        public T details { get; set; }

        public ClientResult<T> ToClientResult<T>()
        {
            var cr = base.ToClientResult();
            return new ClientResult<T>(cr);  
        }
    }
```

In case you have a lot of classes similar to ClientResult, you could use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)