# Why does C# consider a previously non-null member of an instance as null after an upcast?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, clr

While developing a class library for communicating with an external database over JSON, an interesting problem arose where an upcast of an object instance resulted in one of its previously non-null members appear as null.

Many a hairs have been torn out while trying to figure out the cause of this oddity but so far I have been unsuccessful in finding a sane explanation.

Here is an example of the issue:

```
using System;
namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Descendant d = new Descendant();
            d.Attributes.ToString(); // Everything fine here
            Ancestor a = (Ancestor)d;
            a.Attributes.ToString(); // NullPointerException
        }
    }

    class Ancestor
    {
        public interface IAttributes { }
        public IAttributes Attributes;
    }

    class Descendant : Ancestor
    {
        public new DescendantAttributes Attributes;

        public Descendant()
        {
            this.Attributes = new DescendantAttributes();
        }

        public class DescendantAttributes : IAttributes
        {
            public string Name = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Error message: *System.NullReferenceException was unhandled  at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Code\c#\Test\Program.cs:line 12*

.NET version: *4.0*

Environment: *64-bit Windows 2008 R2, Visual Studio 2010*

**Why does it happen?** I mean, unless its a bug there probably is a design rationale behind it. What kind of situations would warrant CLR to consider a previously non-null member of an instance as null after an upcast?

Comment: Because you Descendant class explicitly shadows the Attributes property, thus creating a new and unrelated property. Take a look at [this post that explains the difference between shadowing and overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c).

Comment: Have you tried initializing `Attributes` in `Ancestor`, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `C#`, the `new` keyword can be used as an **operator** , as a **modifier** or a **constraint**. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

- **[new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newoperator) :**   Used to create objects on the heap and invoke constructors.
- **[new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) :**  Used to hide an inherited member from a base class member.
- **[new constraint :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)** Used to restrict types that might be used as arguments for a type parameter in a generic declaration.

**You are using new as a modifier here.**

The `new modifier` is used to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class.In your code, you are shadowing `Attributes` which provides a different implementation at that level of the hierarchy. So as told by Dirk, you are creating a new and unrelated property

```
class Ancestor
    {
        public interface IAttributes { }
        public IAttributes Attributes;
    }

    class Descendant : Ancestor
    {
        public new DescendantAttributes Attributes;  //Shadowing using new modifier

        public Descendant()
        {
            this.Attributes = new DescendantAttributes();
        }

        public class DescendantAttributes : IAttributes
        {
            public string Name = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use `new` modifier you are hiding the inherited property.

```
public new DescendantAttributes Attributes;
```

Look at the below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx

```
When used as a modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides a member that's inherited from a
base class. When you hide an inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the
base-class version. You can hide members without using the new modifier, but the result is a
warning. If you use new to explicitly hide a member, the modifier suppresses this warning and
documents the fact that the derived version is intended as a replacement.
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `shadowing`, you need `overriding` -

```
class Ancestor
{
    public interface IAttributes { }
    public virtual IAttributes Attributes { get; set; } // Make this virtual
}

class Descendant : Ancestor
{
    // Override here OR instead you can omit the declaration at all.
    public override IAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

    public Descendant()
    {
        this.Attributes = new DescendantAttributes();
    }

    public class DescendantAttributes : IAttributes
    {
        public string Name = "";
    }
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) post -

> Suppose you have a base class and you use the base class in all your
>   code instead of the inherited classes, and you use shadow, it will
>   return the values the base class returns instead of following the
>   ineritance tree of the real type of the object.

Comment: Oops..!! Yeah you can't have override on field. Edited to make it a property.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `IAttributes` as type identifier in `Descendant`, it has to be `DescendantAttributes` as other parts of code need to be able to access its members.