# How to achieve same override experience in C# as in Java?

Tags: c#, java

Considering the following Java code:

```
public class overriding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b b = new b();
        a a = (a)b;
        a.Info();
        b.Info();
    }
}

class a {
    void Info() {
        System.out.println("I'm a");
    }
}

class b extends a {
    void Info() {
        System.out.println("I'm b");
    }
}
```

And now let's try to do the same in C#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            b b = new b();
            a a = (a)b;
            a.Info();
            b.Info();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class a
    {
        public void Info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm a");
        }
    }

    class b : a
    {
        public void Info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm b");
        }
    }
}
```

The Java example output

> I'm b
>
> I'm b

The C# version output

> I'm a
>
> I'm b

Is there a way to implement class b so that it prints "I'm b" twice? Please notice i'm not looking at a way to change a.

Comment: This isn't overloading, this is overriding, and you need the keyword override in C# to do it. In Java methods with the same signature override always.

Comment: overloading is when two methods share the same name, but different parameters; overriding is when they share the same method signature.

To override in java, you need the `@Override` annotation, I believe C# has an equivallent of that.

Comment: @Shark You don't need the `@Override` annotation. All that does is throw a compiler error if the method isn't overriding a superclass method. For example, if I had @Override on a method and then changed the signature of the overridden method, @Override would throw a compiler error.

Comment: @Samuel: I guess i learned something today :)

Comment: @Samuel: Correct, I've modified the question.

Comment: [this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) also discusses the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By design. c# has `virtual` methods that you may override in subclasses. The idea is, that the possibility for override is part of the classes contract.

In the Java model, a subclass might break behavior by naming a new method the same as a base method but not providing the proper behavior.

In c# you need to be explicit about this.

Answer (score 9):

In Java, methods are virtual by default. In C# they are not, and you need to use the keywords "virtual" and "override" for the method declarations in classes a and b, respectively.

Comment: Does this mean it's not possible without changing a?

Comment: @Dorus If you don't have permission to make changes to the base class, then no, you can't make a method virtual and, therefore, override its behavior. This is because the vendor of a base class needs to have control over what can and can't be overridden, in order to design the class appropriately.

Comment: You can also use the "new" keyword, but this has limitations.  See my answer above

Answer (score 5):

In `C#` version, you need to use `override` keyword in the `class b` method, and also you need to make the method in `class a` virtual explicitly. In Java, methods are virtual by default. That's not the case in `C#`. You need to tell that explicitly:

```
class a
{
    public virtual void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a");
    }
}

class b : a
{
    public override void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm b");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One major difference between Java and C# is that in Java, methods are `virtual` by default.  To do the same in C#, you need to mark the method `a.Info` as `virtual` and then use the `override` keyword in `b`:

```
class a
{
    public virtual void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a");
    }
}

class b : a
{
    public override void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm b");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use the `new` keyword on class `b` without needing the `virtual` keyword on `a`:

```
class a
{
    public void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a");
    }
}

class b : a
{
    public new void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm b");
    }
}
```

However, this will only produce "I'm b" when the object is of type `b`, but will say "I'm a" when it is cast back to `b`:

```
b myB= new b();
myB.Info();  // This will say "I'm b"

a myA = (a)myB;
myA.Info();  // This will say "I'm a" even though it's really a b object.
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) more info

Comment: Adding 'new' removes the compile warning about hiding a inherited method, but doesn't change any behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Java , we are not using any keywords for method overloading and method overriding. While in C#, you have to use `override` for method overriding explicitly.

```
 public override void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm b");
    }
```