# What would be the right modifier?

Tags: c#

I have the following class with some methods and I would like to use this as a base class of another class.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public string DoWork(string str)
    {
        // some codes...
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

I don't want this class to be instantiated, but the derived class should still use the original implementation of the methods of its base class.

Is it possible? What should be my modifier?

Comment: but abstract don't contain any implementation right?

Comment: @yonan2236 no. Abstract classes can contain concrete methods and properties. Otherwise they wouldn't really be that different from interfaces (apart from declaring non-public members)

Comment: @yonan2236 You can have implementation. It's the `interface` that don't have implementation.

Comment: Is this also true for Java? Does abstract in C# works the same in Java?

Comment: @yonan2236 Same basic principles apply to Java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't want this class to be instantiated, make it an `abstract` class. You can still have implementation on the class.

- [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx)

snippet,

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
    public virtual string DoWork(string str)
    {
        // can have implementation here
        // and classes that inherits can overide this method because of virtual.
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

Comment: why is the method virtual?

Comment: @yonan2236 so the method can be overridden.

Comment: oh, so it means the derived class can have its own implementation of `DoWork` method? right?

Comment: @yonan2236 exactly `:)`

Comment: nice! this is what I'm trying to achive. Many thanks @491243!

Comment: where you from Philippines?

Comment: you can have the default implementation if you don't override this method. yep from dumaguete city `:)`

Comment: I have friends in the Philippines : )

Comment: @Mr.Smith it's not override, but [shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) and it needs to have `new` keyword.

Answer (score 6):

Make `BaseClass` [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx):

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
    // Only available to BaseClass
    private string _myString;

    public string DoWork(string str)
    {
        // Available to everyone
        return _myString;
    }

    protected void DoWorkInternal() {
        // Only available to classes who inherit base class
    }
}
```

This way, you can define your own code within `BaseClass` - but it cannot be initialized directly, it must be inherited from.

Comment: @Mr.Smith I'm not sure. OP says "but the derived class should still use the original implementation of the methods of its base class". I think he does not want `virtual`.